# Vocês gostariam de usar o Traducir.win para traduzir a interface do site?

Tags: debate, localização

A lot of thanks for the translation to [@hkotsubo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo)

---

A interface do Stack Overflow em Português é traduzida pela comunidade. Para tornar isso possível, usamos o [Transifex.com](https://www.transifex.com/). Transifex é uma ótima ferramenta, mas não é perfeita. A integração entre a *engine* da Stack Exchange e o Transifex possui um sério problema - o histórico de traduções pode se perder. Além disso, há outros problemas críticos:

- *Você precisa ter uma conta no Transifex*. Se alguém quiser contribuir com traduções, precisará ter uma conta no Transifex. Esta conta não está ligada com a rede Stack Exchange.
- *Não há notificações*. Por exemplo, quando uma tradução é aprovada, uma sugestão é adicionada, ou quando precisamos importar *strings* do Transifex para a *engine*.

Todas as comunidades internacionais sofriam com estes e vários outros problemas... Até que os usuários do Stack Overflow em Espanhol fizessem uma aplicação chamada [Traducir.win](https://traducir.win/), que resolve alguns destes problemas.

Um resumo sobre o Traducir.win:

- É uma aplicação de código aberto escrita em .NET, disponível no [GitHub](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir). Ela utiliza a API do Transifex (ou seja, é um *add-on* do Transifex, não uma ferramenta dedicada). Qualquer um pode melhorá-la ou sugerir melhorias.
- Você só precisa ter uma conta no Stack Overflow para ter autorização e começar a traduzir. Moderadores possuem permissões de revisor por padrão.
- Possui seu próprio banco de dados de *strings* traduzidas. No caso de uma  «tradução ser perdida» no Transifex, Traducir.win tentará recuperar o histórico disponível.
- Você pode marcar uma *string* específica como "tradução urgente".
- Há notificações para browsers quando uma nova *string* é adicionada, uma nova tradução é sugerida, um CM precisa importar *strings*, etc.
- Há uma lista de tradutores e suas respectivas contribuições.
- Você pode procurar *strings* usando expressões regulares.

Acho que estas funcionalidades podem simplificar muito o processo de tradução e dar a oportunidade de melhorar a interface a um número maior de usuários do SOpt.

- [Vídeo sobre a aplicação (em inglês)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbpoWXctN3Y).

Pergunta para a comunidade:

> *Vocês poderiam me dizer o que acham de mudar do Transifex para o  Traducir.win?*

Traducir.win está sendo usado pelos sites do Stack Overflow em Espanhol, Japonês e Russo. Vale ressaltar que se começarmos a usar o Traducir.win, não será possível traduzir pelo Transifex, já que o Traducir.win irá  “reescrever” quaisquer traduções diretamente no Transifex.

Por favor deixem seu *feedback*, o que vocês acham?

---

Adicionando - e traduzindo - informações [do comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7498/voc%C3%AAs-gostariam-de-usar-o-traducir-win-para-traduzir-a-interface-do-site#comment28984_7498) do [g3rv4](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/103127/g3rv4):

> A aplicação é de código aberto, podem ser feitas queries online no banco de produção, tudo é logado e os *backups* do banco são feitos duas vezes por dia (e qualquer um pode baixá-los). E com certeza falta alguma documentação. Caso tenham alguma dúvida, por favor me digam :-) E também estarei [no chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win).

Comment: O que precisamos fazer para utilizar o traducir.win?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Hi! Just agree to use it :) Then I will ask Gervasio (g3rv4) to deploy an app for SOpt.

Comment: Well... I agree.

Comment: hi folks! (sorry about the English, my Portuguese is... forgettable). The app is [open source](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir), the prod db can be queried online, everything is logged and db backups are built twice a day (and anybody can download them). We're lacking some documentation for sure. Please let me know if you have any questions :) also, I'm going to be [on the chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win)

Answer (score 15):

Pelas funcionalidades, vejo que é uma ferramenta com grande potencial de nos ajudar a resolver [este tipo de problema realmente irritante](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A28595%20%5Btradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D), que é quando um update feito no site remove todas as traduções já feitas.

Apesar de não dominar o idioma inglês, eu apoio a mudança, creio que há muitos membros na comunidade que tem uma boa noção e estão sempre dispostos a colaborar.

Só gostaria de sugerir que fosse feito um passo-a-passo em forma de tópico aqui mesmo no meta, para que sirva de ponto de partida para os que quiserem se aventurar nas traduções.

No mais, deixo meus parabéns aos usuários do SOes pela ótima iniciativa em criar essa ferramenta.