# Estamos mudando para o Traducir.win para as traduções da interface

Tags: debate, status-pronto, localização, transifex

A lot of thanks to [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) for the translation!

---

Semana passada iniciei [a discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7498/17539) sobre se devemos ou não utilizar o *Traducir.win* para traduzir a interface de usuário do site. *Traducir* é um projeto *open source* que foi criado pelos usuários do Stack Overflow em Espanhol com o [@g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4?tab=profile) liderando o projeto. A aplicação funciona como um *add-on* do *Transifex*. A discussão não trouxe nenhum retorno negativo, ao mesmo tempo a aplicação possui algumas vantagens (tais como notificações, a habilidade de sinalizar textos como urgentes, etc.). Então, vamos tentar?

Por favor, observe:

> Durante o final de semana, 29 e 30/12/2018, [@g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4?tab=profile) ativará o *Traducir* para a comunidade de língua portuguesa.

Isto significa que todas as traduções feitas no *Transifex.com* desde sexta-feita a noite podem ser perdidas. Por favor, esperem pelo *Traducir* e utilize-o para as traduções.

Lançaremos o *Traducir* no modo experimental, que durará por um mês. Durante este tempo, a comunidade precisa entender se iremos continuar com o *Traducir* ou se voltaremos ao *Transifex*. Por favor, utilizem o *Traducir* o máximo posśivel durante este período para que possamos tomar a decisão correta.

Comment: I will post on this question once it’s been enabled ;)

Comment: Hi! We need some attention to approve translations on Traducir.win :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Feito!

Sinta-se à vontade para visitar [pt.traducir.win](https://pt.traducir.win). Você poderá entrar com a sua conta do Stack Overflow em Português.

Temos três funções no sistema:

- Revisores: estes são os moderadores. Eles podem aprovar uma sugestão e quando isso acontece, ela é enviada para o Transifex
- Usuários confiáveis: são usuários escolhidos pelos revisores para ajudar com a fila. Eles podem pré-aprovar (ou rejeitar) sugestões feitas por usuários regulares. Eles ajudam a aliviar um pouco da carga de trabalho dos revisores.
- Usuários regulares: Qualquer usuário com uma conta SOpt que faça login

O workflow é o seguinte:

- Um usuário adiciona uma sugestão (pode ser para uma string não traduzida ou uma traduzida). Neste ponto, ela está no *status* "aguardando revisão".
- Um usuário confiável pode revisá-la. Se eles dizem que a sugestão é ruim, o processo termina aí. Se eles dizem que é boa, é então passa a ser uma "sugestão aprovada aguardando revisão".
- Um revisor pode revê-la. Se for aprovada, ela é alterada no Transifex.

Além disso, usuários confiáveis e revisores podem ignorar strings (eu fiz isso com todas as strings do [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)... esse recurso não vai entrar em sites internacionais no futuro próximo). Quando uma string é ignorada, ela não aparecerá nos resultados de pesquisa ou nas estatísticas.

E mais uma coisa que qualquer um pode usar é "*Mark as Urgent*" (Marcar como Urgente). Quando alguém o faz, ele sinaliza que provavelmente deve ser traduzido o mais rápido possível. A ideia é que as pessoas que vêem uma string em inglês no site possam marcá-la como urgente para que esta seja traduzida.

Se você quer ser atualizado sobre tudo que acontece, pode escolher receber notificações web push (funciona apenas no Chrome, Firefox e Opera) e você pode ser notificado de coisas que importam para você.

O aplicativo sem dúvida precisa de alguma documentação... então fique à vontade para perguntar (e talvez contribuir com a documentação?) e [dar uma olhada no código](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) :)

Se você quiser consultar o banco de dados ao vivo, pode ver [as instruções aqui](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/docs/USING_REDASH.md)... e você pode sempre baixar os backups de produção em [db-backups.traducir.win](https://db-backups.traducir.win). Eles são gerados duas vezes por dia.

---

Done!

Feel free to visit [pt.traducir.win](https://pt.traducir.win), and you should be able to log in with your Stack Overflow em Português account.

We have three roles in the system:

- Reviewers: these are the mods. They can approve a suggestion and when that happens, it's pushed to Transifex
- Trusted users: these are users chosen by reviewers to help with the queue. They can pre-approve (or reject) suggestions made by regular users. They help keep a bit of load off the reviewer's plates.
- Regular users: Any user with a SOpt account that logs in

The workflow is as follows:

- A user adds a suggestion (it could be for an untranslated string or a translated one). At this point, it's "awaiting review"
- A trusted user can review it. If they say it's bad, then that's it. If they say it's good, it's then an "approved suggestion awaiting review"
- A reviewer can review it. If they approve it, it makes it into Transifex.

Also, trusted users and reviewers can ignore strings (I did that with all the Teams strings... that feature is not going to make it into international sites in the near future). When a string is ignored, it won't appear on search results or on the stats.

And the last thing anybody can use is "Mark as Urgent". When somebody does it, it signals that we should probably translate it asap. The idea is that people that see a string in English on the site can mark it as urgent so that folks translate it.

If you want to be kept in the loop of when things happen, you can choose to receive web push notifications (works only in Chrome, Firefox and Opera) and you can be notified of things that matter to you.

The app definitely needs some documentation... so feel free to ask away (maybe contribute with docs?) and [check out its code](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) :)

If you want to query the live database, you can see [instructions here](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/docs/USING_REDASH.md)... and you can always download the prod backups from [db-backups.traducir.win](https://db-backups.traducir.win). They are generated twice a day.

Comment: I believe there are still strings belonging to Teams. A quick search for the term show a few strings I believe belong there (e.g. '$adminName$ needs your help to launch the Team' )

Comment: yeah, that was something I did on SOes only :) also, that should be an ongoing effort (since Teams strings are added daily). So that's something that if the community *could* do if there was an interest.

Comment: If you let me as "Trusted user" I can try to remove them (at least the most obvious ones...)

Comment: that sounds great, but I'd rather have mods (the real ones, those that were elected) and the community choose how they want the process to work. We can even have reviewers that are not mods if the community thought it's a good idea. Feel free to ask here on meta, mi role here is to facilitate the usage of the system... not so much to decide how it's going to be used ;)

Comment: Thats fine for me, if the mods are gonna handle that.

Comment: I love to see you willing to put the time to make this work :) and I'd love to have folks interested in it as trusted users / reviewers (right now we have 57 suggestions awaiting review)... just want to allow the community to make its decisions... so let me know if I can help you nominate for anything.

Comment: @g3rv4 I've made some changes in the translation, there's only one thing that I'm not sure if I did it right. When you say *"all the Teams strings"*, are you talking about the strings in [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)?

Comment: thanks @hkotsubo! yes, I'm referring to the Stack Overflow for Teams related strings

Comment: @g3rv4 Ok, I've updated the translation with that info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see there is an improvement in the management part of translations, however the experience in translation is way worse.

I tried the new tool this afternoon, and a few problems I saw:

- There is no glossary or suggestion as there is in transifex (what makes it easier to translate a single term in two different ways since you are not presented with similar previous translations)
- There is no pagination in the results page! So when I click to see the strings without translation I can only see 200 and thats all.
- There is no auto-save as there is in transifex...How did I found that? Obviously the worst way. I was translating a big text and then by accident dismissed the modal and all my work was lost!

To make the change worth it at least the last two issues should be addressed and the first would be very helpful.

**UPDATE**:

After a quick chat, it seems that only reported strings are translated as a way of optimizing efforts, since there is no way of knowing exactly which strings are really used in their portuguese version.
This way, I don't think these issues are that important anymore.

---

Eu vejo que há uma melhoria na parte de gestão das traduções, todavia a experiência de tradução está muito pior.

Eu testei a nova ferramenta esta tarde e já constatei alguns problemas:

- Não tem glossário nem sugestões que nem no Transifex (o que facilita a tradução de um mesmo termo de duas maneiras diferentes uma vez que não temos acesso a traduções similares anteriores)
- Não tem paginação! Quando eu clico pra ver as strings sem tradução só consigo ver 200 e é isso.
- Não tem auto-salvamento que nem no Transifex...como eu descobri? Obviamente da pior maneira. Estava traduzindo um texto enorme daí sem querer fechei a janela de edição e todo meu trabalho foi perdido!

Acho que para valer a mudança pelo menos os dois últimos deveriam ser resolvidos e o primeiro seria muito útil.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**:
Depois de uma rápida conversa no chat, parece  que por uma questão de otimização de esforços, traduzimos apenas textos dos quais as pessoas fazem alguma reclamação, uma vez que não há como saber exatamente quais strings são realmente usadas na versão em português.
Deste modo, não creio que esses problemas que comentei aqui sejam realmente importantes.

Comment: feel free to [create an issue](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues) and we're happy to discuss ideas to implement them. Re: pagination, I'm a bit skeptical about its usefulness... the idea is not to translate 100% of the strings on the system, but only those that actually appear on the site. I'd expect people to see an untranslated string -> search for it -> translate it instead of going through all the untranslated strings.

Comment: also worth noting that this is an experiment, and if SOpt wanted to go back to Transifex, that's really easy to do :) the only thing we can't do is having both systems work concurrently (since traducir does a dump of all its strings every 10 minutes).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It's sad to hear that some of your work has been lost. On the other hand this is a community effort, the app is open sourced. As g3rv4 said there is an issue tracker where you can suggest an improvement. Moreover you can implement it yourself and commit the changes and all international communities will benefit from having it.

Comment: International communities are all very different, as well as users. For example, if we talk about a glossary, on SOru we do not have the problem because we have [glossary on meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/6) and at the same time Transifex does not handle the Russian language  very well (a word may vary a lot from case to case but still has the same meaning). I want to say that it's very difficult to predict all use cases before actually launching and using the app.

Comment: Could you please tell me If you think that those are the "show stoppers" and we cannot move forward without them (means, we need to switch back to pure Transifex)?

Comment: @g3rv4 Well, we have two different understanding of translations. Before adressing other points raised here, we had better reach a consensus.  I've always thought the ideia was to translate most strings (with exceptions like Team`s). 
Its very hard to have access to all possible strings, since lots of them are very specifics (e.g. the message you receive when achieving certain rep, or when you you receive too many downvotes), we are not supposed to translate these? Or we expect that the people receiving them warn us about missing translations?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky If the idea is to translate strictly the strings people complain about in the site (or that we can found) then well, the new tool works kind of fine (even though the missing glossary/history might incur in distinct translation for the same term).

Comment: @carla the app was built with SOes in mind (because all the devs are SOes users so far). Adding pagination is not a big deal, so feel free to open an issue and let's discuss it there. Also, if you'd rather wait until we decide if we want continue using it on SOpt, that makes a lot of sense. Nothing here is final, and the community will have the final say. What I can't promise is time to work on new features... but I'd be happy to review PRs :)

Comment: also, deal-breakers for SOpt could be summarized. We could decide to switch to Transifex until somebody has the time and intentions to implement those missing things. If this is not a good fit for SOpt, we won't push it ;)

Comment: @g3rv4 I don't know if I've sounded ironic or something, but that is a true doubt. :) Do we use those kind of translations (e.g https://pt.traducir.win/string/6521)?  I didn't create an issue or tried to solve the problems I mentioned because I believe they are strongly related on how and where we use the translated strings.

Comment: @carla I'm not following, would you have 5 mins to talk [on the chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win)?