# Tradução - pequena parte do site

Tags: bug, internacionalização

Bom dia, estava a navegar pelo site e a ler algumas perguntas sem resposta nomeadamente [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282670/transformar-dados-de-html-que-est%C3%A3o-dentro-do-txt-em-tabelas-excel?rq=1) e reparei que no fim da pergunta como não existe qualquer resposta existe o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alerto para o facto de que a primeira parte está em Português e a segunda está em Inglês.

Foi uma não tradução intencional ou deve ser corrigida?

Comment: Pode ver em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7515/5878 como serão feitas as traduções da interface. Você pode colaborar fazendo o login pelo SOpt

Comment: Desculpa @Anderson não consegui perceber como colocar o texto em espera de tradução.

Comment: Para poder enviar uma sugestão, você precisa entrar (no canto superior direito, onde diz "Log In!")

Comment: Pronto, está feito. Abraços.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta resposta é uma tradução automática, sinta-se livre para melhorá-la.

Eu fiz uma pesquisa de [Search a link to this](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Share%20a%20link%20to%20this) e lá você pode ver as duas cordas que correspondem a essa pesquisa.

O que não tem Google+ é o que você está vendo lá, então você pode enviar uma nova sugestão.

Acho que a tradução deveria ser `Compartilhe um link para esta [pergunta]($link$) por [e-mail]($mailto$), no [Twitter]($tw$) ou [Facebook]($fb$).` mas eu não falo português.

Você pode ver o processo completo aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione isso, e uma vez que um revisor o aprove, ele chegará ao site.

---

I did a search of [Search a link to this](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Share%20a%20link%20to%20this) and there you can see the two strings that match that search.

The one without Google+ is the one you are seeing there, so you can send a new suggestion.

I'm guessing the translation should be `Compartilhe um link para esta [pergunta]($link$) por [e-mail]($mailto$), no [Twitter]($tw$) ou [Facebook]($fb$).` but I don't speak Portuguese.

You can see the full process here:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Once a reviewer approves it, it will make it to the site.

Comment: Pronto, está feito. Abraços.