# Vamos ativar a nova página de fazer uma pergunta!

Tags: debate, perguntas, qualidade

Muito obrigado a [@CypherPotato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24529/cypherpotato) pela tradução.

---

Existiram duas iniciativas interessantes no Stack Overflow em Inglês no ano passado. A primeira é o [Assistente de Pergunta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/22/impact-of-ask-question-wizard/). O objeto dessa iniciativa era ajudar a perguntar navegando e questionando sobre a pergunta e brevemente melhorar o resultado final. Analisando os resultados da iniciativa nós entendemos que precisamos pensar sobre algumas mudanças na página de criação de pergunta. Nós decidimos [fazer uma pesquisa](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) (a segunda iniciativa)! As principais questões da pesquisa foram:

- Quais foram as experiências das pessoas fazendo uma pergunta no Stack Overflow?
- Que informação os usuários precisam antes de fazer uma questão no Stack Overflow?
- Como o Stack Overflow se encaixa na resolução de problemas das pessoas?

Pesquisadores olharam as informações, conduziram entrevistas um a um. A atenção foi prestada a ambos indicadores quantitativos e qualitativos. Eles falaram tanto com usuários com alta reputação quanto os com baixa...

#### Resultado: uma nova página para perguntar

[image]

A nova página para criar perguntas é uma união do assistente de perguntas e da clássica página antiga. De acordo com os dados disponíveis, nós podemos assumir que essa nova página de perguntas irá criar novas perguntas com melhor qualidade para tanto os novos usuários quanto aos já experientes.

<sub>[Mais sobre essa pesquisa (em inglês).](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)</sub>

Você sabe o que é mais interessante nesta história? A nova página de pergunta pode ser ativada no nosso site!

#### O que precisamos fazer para ativar a nova página de fazer uma pergunta?

Nós apenas precisamos de uma pequena ajuda de nossos usuários: mesmo que a nova página esteja completamente pronta para ser lançada no Stack Overflow em Português, ainda existe um obstáculo. Traduções. Maioria dos textos na nova página não estão traduzidos. Eu tenho certeza que todos concordam que é uma ideia controversa ativar uma página em inglês neste site.

#### Como alguém pode ajudar?

Nós estamos procurando usuários que desejem ajudar na tradução de textos não traduzidos. Individualmente para eles, nós vamos ativar a nova página de pergunta em seguida, então nós iremos ver os textos sendo traduzido ao decorrer do tempo.

Se você está disposto a ajudar, por favor, envie-me um e-mail  (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) ou deixe-me saber nos comentários desta questão.

Vamos lançar a nova página juntos, e espero que ela irá ajudar nossos colegas a fazerem apenas perguntas de alta qualidade! =)

> Nota de edição: você também pode ajudar a traduzir nossos textos aqui no [Traducir](https://pt.traducir.win/). [Veja aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7515/estamos-mudando-para-o-traducir-win-para-as-tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-da-interface) como usar o Traducir e o que é este site.

**Atualizar**

Criei um arquivo csv com todas as strings para traduzir para todos os idiomas: http://assets.rudevs.ru/extra/new_ask_question_page.csv

Se você quiser ajudar, adicione suas traduções de contribuição em https://pt.traducir.win

Comment: And why not use https://pt.traducir.win/ as the rest of the site?

Comment: @Woss todas as strings estão no Transifex / Traducir. Queremos permitir o acesso antecipado a alguns usuários para que eles possam verificar se está tudo bem (e se não estiver bem, ajude-nos a corrigir).

Comment: Pessoalmente não vejo como esta mudança realmente melhoraria em algo, eu acredito que exista uma série de problemas de UX (envolvendo UI ou não) nos sites da rede que são inclusive mencionados no "META.se", problemas que me parecem realmente relevantes, mas ao mesmo tempo parecem serem ignorados. Aqui mesmo no SOpt nasceu uma postagem sobre o assunto. (Link about this: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/3635)

Comment: "Translate": Personally, I don't see how this change would really improve something, I believe that there are a number of UX problems (involving UI or not) on the websites of the network that are even mentioned in "META.se", problems that I think are really relevant, but it looks like they're totally ignored. In "SOpt" there is a post about this.

Comment: Já foi feito algo sobre isso?

Comment: @Maniero Olá! Feliz em te ver! Sim, com uma tonelada de ajuda do hkotsubo, a página é traduzida. Espero ativá-lo para todos os usuários em breve.

Comment: Já foi ativada? Se não, qual é a previsão?

Comment: Oi @Woss! Espero que tenhamos o recurso ativado esta semana (se tudo der certo).

Comment: @Nicolas, o que seria "tudo"?