# A nova página de fazer uma pergunta realmente será um sucesso?

Tags: debate, perguntas, qualidade

Conforme [anunciado anteriormente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8209/5878), a "nova" página de fazer uma pergunta [foi ativada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8252/a-nova-p%C3%A1gina-para-fazer-perguntas-chegou).

Junto com a notícia da ativação, temos a afirmação de um funcionário da SO (empresa):

> De acordo com os dados disponíveis, nós podemos assumir que essa nova página de perguntas irá criar novas perguntas com melhor qualidade para tanto os novos usuários quanto aos já experientes.

A suposição é feita com base no histórico já conhecido, mas surgem as seguintes duvidas:

- Como será feito o acompanhamento dentro do SOpt para confirmar se existirá essa melhora de qualidade?
- E o que acontece se não houver a melhora?
- Ou pior, e se for constatado que a nova página piorou o processo de perguntar?
- Quanto tempo será necessário de análise para concluir o sucesso (ou não) da nova página?

Relacionada: [Quais são as métricas que a SE utiliza para medir progresso de um site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7987/5878)

Comment: Eu não acho que piorará, mas também não melhorará. A gente sabe o padrão das pessoas que perguntam aqui. Em geral o problema delas é ter pouco comprometimento com sua própria pergunta, você pode fazer o que for e a esmagadora maioria não vai pra frente, um dos motivos dos experientes terem desistido, você perde muito tempo para pouco ou zero resultado. Colocar informações a mais para ajudar a pessoa já foi feito pelos usuários e não costuma resolver. Pode melhorar um pouco? Pode, mas só aqueles casos que a UX realmente estava prejudicando.

Comment: Somente a exigência da pessoa se comprometer um pouco mais, o sistema avisando quando que algo pode sair errado em alguns casos, perguntar para a pessoa algumas coisas para ela se certificar que está dentro das regras pode fazer cair a quantidade de perguntas de baixa qualidade (pode cair todas, eu não sei se melhorará muito o que as pessoas fazem, mas filtrará). Se tiver menos perguntas não é ruim, as pessoas terão mais tempo para se concentrar nos casos que passa e poderá sair mais qualidade dali.

Comment: É o que eu ando falando, falta comunidade, quem fazia a diferença sumiu (conforme antecipado) e os novos (não todos) só sabem reclamar e fugir.

Comment: Me parece pura perfumaria, na pratica estão acreditando em um UX que nem sequer de fato é possivel afirmar ou provar, mudar coisas para um "box" e acreditar que as pessoas irão ler é tipo colar um adesivo do lado da porta, achando que as pessoas vão ler as regras antes de passar pela porta, com tantos problemas que poderiam melhorar nossa experiência, escolhem resolver algo que nem era um problema de fato, ou melhor que nem era a origem dos problemas...  só a experiência de muitos irá poder confirmar se melhorou, é errado a SE afirmar que é melhor, creio que não é assim que funciona UX.

Comment: Por que o downvote na pergunta? Ele esta questionando, me parece, e não afirmando que vai ser melhor (e nem ao contrário). Quem negativou poderia justificar ao menos aonde esta o problema? Lembre-se, downvotes e upvotes no META não contam como score, compartilhar ideias aqui é geralmente útil a comunidade.

Comment: Tem um post no blog do SO com os números do teste A/B que eles fizeram para este formulário novo: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/

Comment: Relacionado: ["Qual o critério da página de fazer pergunta para determinar a qualidade de uma pergunta? É possível melhorá-lo?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8717/112052)

Answer (score 16):

Confesso que quando esta nova página foi anunciada, eu achei - em um misto de esperança e ingenuidade - que ela seria como um "*wizard*" mesmo: um **assistente**, ou seja, algo um pouco mais inteligente que um campo de texto com alguns botões, que ajudasse e orientasse o usuário a preencher todas as informações necessárias, etc. [Pois é assim que ele é chamado oficialmente pela SE](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/22/impact-of-ask-question-wizard/) (*Ask Question Wizard*).

Quando o Nicolas pediu ajuda para traduzir a página para o português, eu me voluntariei e me deram acesso a ela (para que eu tivesse o contexto em que as strings são usadas, ajudando na tradução). A página é assim:

[image: nova página de fazer pergunta]

Podemos ver que as "dicas" ficam do lado direito, e elas seriam bem mais úteis se não ficassem em um canto onde não há garantia de que alguém vai ler. Mas talvez eu esteja especulando demais, vamos a um teste mais prático.

Eu preenchi o título e o corpo da pergunta com o seguinte texto:

> Título: "teste de nova pergunta"
>
> fazendo um teste para saber se o wizard vai funcionar.
>
> pois lorem ipsum dolor sit ament

E coloquei uma *tag* qualquer (acho que foi [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), mas não importa qual foi, só coloquei uma porque a página valida se tem pelo menos uma *tag* preenchida). Então cliquei no botão "*Review your question*" e apareceu isso aqui:

[image: fail]

Pois é, no canto direito aparece uma mensagem dizendo que "*nosso sistema automático verificou maneiras de melhorar sua pergunta e não encontrou nenhuma*".

Isso mostra que esta página não tem inteligência nenhuma, não verifica nada, e que só colocaram algumas mensagens no canto para "ajudar". Sabemos que *geralmente* perguntas que só tem duas ou três frases curtas são ruins e fora do escopo (costumam ser algo do tipo "*queria fazer um programa que faz X, pesquisei muito e não achei nada*"). Enfim, perguntas com duas frases curtas dificilmente são boas e dentro do escopo, mas nem essa verificação mais básica foi feita.

Para mim, a UI deveria tentar "forçar" o usuário a ler todas as informações e só prosseguir se ele realmente preenchesse tudo.

O pior é que o passo 3 da primeira imagem (que diz "*show some code*") sequer apareceu de novo, pois logo abaixo já apareceu o botão "*Post your question*", ou seja, a pergunta já seria criada (e isso eu não fiz para não poluir o site). Claro que nem toda pergunta necessariamente deve ter código - embora eu ache que a maioria deva ter - mas se a UI nem sequer faz o usuário considerar se deve ou não colocar código, então é difícil achar que ela vai de fato ajudar a melhorar alguma coisa.

Dada esta pequena experiência com a nova página, perdi minhas esperanças com ela. Do jeito que está, não vai ajudar quase nada a melhorar. Talvez uma pequena, ínfima porcentagem de pessoas de fato leia e siga as novas instruções, mas sabemos pelo histórico que pessoas assim já têm a tendência de se preocupar mais com as regras e acabariam seguindo-as com ou sem esse *wizard*.

---

## Atualizando...

Ontem (10/02/2022) [fiz uma pergunta no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/542601/112052), e para minha surpresa, apareceu um aviso dizendo que a pergunta "*parece subjetiva*" e tinha "*boa chance de ser fechada*":

[image: Subjetiva? Sério?]

E eu pensando que a página não analisava nada. Na verdade é pior, ela analisa porcamente e classifica erroneamente uma pergunta legítima como sendo fora de escopo.

Já isso aqui ela acha OK:

[image: Isso é ok? Sério? Não tem como melhorar mesmo?]

Ou seja, uma pergunta legítima, com [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e tudo mais, é classificada como "subjetiva" e que "pode ser fechada". Já uma linha de texto sem sentido é classificada como "OK, não tem o que melhorar". Achei isso tão ridículo e absurdo que [reportei como *bug*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8717/112052).

Não tem um jeito educado de dizer isso: essa página de fazer pergunta é uma grande piada de mau gosto...

Comment: Foi o que [eu disse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8247/3635), apesar de não ter entrado em detalhes, pq presumi que quem perguntava já tinha testado, o que eu disse foi o exemplo da *"porta de acesso"*, na lateral e sem forçar não resolve de muita coisa e o formulário não tem inteligência e o pior de tudo, eles estão promovendo algo baseado em achismo como se fosse a solução definitiva, algo que dá pra notar que é quase o mesmo de sempre mas com uma "skin" nova no final.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, concordo com sua resposta (votei nela ontem, mas só tive tempo de responder hoje), eu só quis complementar, detalhando um pouco mais e dando um exemplo de uso, já que nem todos tiveram a chance de ver e testar a nova página.

Answer (score 5):

Até aonde sei UX (experiência) não é se afirma com algo "X é melhor", sem testar de fato, que parece o que a empresa/responsáveis esta fazendo, eu vou colocar um exemplo:

Raramente se uma porta de acesso tiver um placa com regras, na parede lateral próxima, as pessoas irão parar pra ler, e pior se for aonde muitas pessoas passam, o que geralmente dificulta de ficarmos muito tempo perto da porta e placa e mesmo que alguém pare para ler, raramente vão entender de primeira (claro que há exceções) ou vão ter "tempo" pra ler aquilo (ao menos é a desculpa mais comum).

UX não é algo que "se afirma", até algumas coisas dá para afirmar, mas com certeza **não é receita de bolo**, você pode até ter uma base ou ideia razoável inicialmente, mas geralmente "a pratica" é quem vai lhe afirmar se algo foi eficiente e até o feedback das pessoas devem contar, mas isso só depois de testado e não adianta vir com um *grupinho de usuário experientes* com o site e eles dizerem que esta "lindo" ou "bom", temos comunidades gigantescas, com usuários experientes e inexperientes e o experientes acredito que nem vão sentir tanta diferença, pois **geralmente** eles conhecem e aceitam as regras e entendem o que é "qualidade" na hora de perguntar.

Ainda sim alguns experientes interessados podem sim avaliar bem, mas o que quero dizer é que só se eles quiserem fazer, porque na pratica geralmente o teste tem que ser voltado para quem costuma fazer um mal uso das perguntas, se o intuito do novo formulário é melhorar a qualidade, então isso tem que ser testado baseado nos usuários inexperientes, que as vezes surpreendem ao conseguir fazer absurdo.

Quando digo experiente não estou falando de ter uma conta a 4 anos ou mais, estou falando de frequentar o site e ter um numero considerável de postagens com aceitação razoável e que provavelmente converse com outros usuários experientes e saiba receber uma critica construtiva e até dicas, agora nos demais, mesmo com uma conta de 5 anos, não dá pra afirmar experiência, mas são estes **sem experiência** que interessam para afirmar se algo novo foi realmente melhor, se alguém como **menos** experiência conseguir usar bem e entender bem a ferramenta/site.

Agora **não** adianta "entrevistar" umas **100 pessoas especificas** e com uma razoável diferença sair afirmando que vai melhorar a qualidade das perguntas, o pior de tudo nisto é que tem **pessoas experientes** que confundem UX com o que lhes agrada visualmente e eu vou deixar bem claro, as pessoas confundem sim e é quase sempre, e o pior, tem gente que adora falhar que entende de UX, mas é mentira, ela provavelmente esta mentindo pra ela mesma (sem saber, "achismo"), mesmo as vezes sendo da área que usa bastante disto, o que vejo de respostas aqui no site de pessoas falando coisas erradas sobre UX, e nem estou dizendo que é *"exatamente errado"*, estou dizendo que afirmam sem ter testes e muitas vezes baseados em *"achismo"*

Vamos ao que interessa, eu **não acredito** que este formulário tenha sido pensado nas pessoas inexperientes, ou ao menos não foram as pessoas consultadas, quem foi consultado provavelmente tem muita experiência no site e algumas opiniões podem sim ser boas, mas a maioria pode ser uma série de problemas, do que eu já disse antes:

- achismo
- pessoa já sabe usar que nem notaria a diferença
- confundir aparência com UX

Eu fiz o teste hoje no SOen, criei uma pergunta que era [**uma réplica** (precisa de score alto pra acessar)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60434537/1518921) de uma [**pergunta antiga**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2743190/1518921), só mudei um pouco o titulo, o formulário não me barrou, ao contrário foi direto:

> [image: pergunta que criei para testar o novo formulário]

O sistema não me barrou em **NENHUM momento**, então o formulário com um *wizard* meia-boca não me parece solução de verdade.

---

### Automatizar seria um bom começo para resolver problema de qualidade nas perguntas

Os sites da rede tem de muitos problemas UX, este formulário de pergunta nem de longe era o problema, ou melhor a mudança não mudou em quase nada, algumas automatizações (como checagens) que gerem algum tipo de bloqueio para uma ação incorreta seriam muito melhor que a interface gráfica (no mínimo os funcionários da empresa devem ter confundido UX com UI), isso sim me parecia uma razoável melhoria.

Por exemplo, tem muita gente postando perguntas do site principal `pt.stackoverflow.com` no `pt.meta.stackoverflow.com`, muitas mesmo, não é uma vez ou outra, é quase todos os dias, mesmo com o icone do lado do logo escrito `meta` e nas tags do formulário não existindo as tags das tecnologias que a pessoa vai perguntar

Eu nem sei como a pessoa vem parar aqui no META, nem faz sentido ela chegar aqui pra perguntar, a única coisa plausível, que precisa ser investigado para termos certeza, é que as pessoas acham que o META é lugar para fazer perguntas fora do escopo, ou que é algum lugar de ajuda exclusiva.

Neste caso ou em outros, acho que o formulário ser mais inteligente e detectar o erro previamente e bloquear até a pessoa corrigir ajudaria muito, sei que é um trabalho complexo de se realizar, mas não estamos mais de em 2008, acho que para uma empresa deste porte, com diversos funcionários no mínimo algo mais razoável já era para termos.

---

### Uma série de sugestões que "nos" parecem boas para melhorar o site

- [Se você pudesse alterar QUALQUER coisa no site, o que mudaria?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/3635)

Claro que nem todas são boas de verdade, algumas são opiniões de pessoas com menos experiência, que são só desejos e não melhoria de fato.

Comment: Quem negativou pode apontar o ponto que discorda da postagem? E se é um ou mais pontos