# A nova página para fazer perguntas chegou!

Tags: debate

Oba! A nova página para fazer perguntas foi ativada para todos usuários no Stack Overflow em Português,

[image]

> **TL;DR;**
>
> A nova página foi desenhada com o objetivo de ajudar os usuários a navegarem no site e prontamente oferecer dicas de como melhorar a pergunta. Essa novidade é uma combinação do “Ask a question Wizard” e da página padrão para perguntas.
>
> [Mais sobre a iniciativa no blog (em inglês).](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)

Por favor nos ajudem a agradecer a equipe de desenvolvimento e nosso incrível tradutor [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) sem o qual a comunidade não teria essa página!

Ficaremos felizes em receber seu feedback aqui mesmo =)

Comment: Serve esse feedback: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8247/3635 ? (sou usuário no SOen também, já havia testado lá)

Comment: Acabei de acessar e vi que muitos textos ainda estão em inglês (dei reload, limpei o cache, acessei em aba anônima, etc, e continua em inglês). Quando as traduções serão aplicadas?

Comment: Vi agora, várias partes ainda estão em inglês

Comment: Por que temos que agradecer a equipe, não são parte da *staff*? Talvez agradecer a quem ajudou comunitáriamente, como o @hkotsubo, seja OK, mas agradecer por algo que nem é garantido de funcionar e só esta baseado em suposições ou afirmações sem ter testes da comunidade não seja certo. Por falar nisso eu já havia testado no SOen e aqui, eu não creio que o usuários que criam perguntas com problemas graves de qualidade irão parar pra ler o "suposto wizard" (na verdade nem chega a ser wizard, tá ali do "lado parado", muda pra um coisa ou outra). Meu feedback está no primeiro comentário.

Comment: Hey @hkotsubo Se as strings estiverem traduzidas, elas já devem estar no sistema. [Vejo algumas seqüências de caracteres que ainda não foram aprovadas](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?suggestionsStatus=3). Talvez seja esse o motivo?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky E por que não verificaram se todas as strings estavam aprovadas antes de lançar a página? Pois deixar assim com vários textos em inglês é pior, era melhor ter esperado a aprovação...

Comment: Se melhorar, será bem pouco, com tanta coisa que poderia adicionar/mudar, teve poucas alterações. Não cheguei a testar, mas pelo que vi em alguns posts esse "Wizard" não passa de uma "mini página de ajuda incorporada", mas que no fim não ajuda em quase nada. Se pelo menos fosse um modal obrigatório (deve ir passando até o último, sem poder pular) já ajudaria mais um pouquinho. Também acho que ele poderia ser mais inteligente, exemplo, já que tem a busca por perguntas semelhantes pelo título, adicionar uma comparação com o conteúdo e alertar caso for parecido não parece ser algo tão complicado

Comment: O Wizard mesmo não será adotado, provavelmente eles tem dados que mostram que melhora a qualidade do que é postado, mas reduz bastante o número de perguntas, porque a maioria das pessoas que fazem perguntas de baixa qualidade não querem fazer algo melhor, elas querem o ruim e o wizard seria um incômodo para elas. O que a comunidade acha bom a SE acha ruim, é uma questão de quem busca qualidade e quem busca quantidade. Pra comunidade, "impedir" perguntas ruins por obrigar a pessoa pensar no que está fazendo é algo bom. Podia melhorar 5% (bem mais detalhes) ou 50% (wizard), optaram por 0,5%.

Comment: @hkotsubo É uma boa pergunta! Eu realmente confio em você e em outros membros. Para mim, quando pergunto a você ou a outra pessoa se estamos prontos, a resposta "sim" significa que está tudo bem. Sim, verifico se o sistema apresenta alguns problemas importantes, pois pode haver erros de interpretação. Ao mesmo tempo, a regra geral é a mesma: este é o seu site e a sua comunidade, meu papel é ajudá-lo e fazer tudo o que puder para o seu sucesso.

Comment: Se você tem alguma idéia de como posso ajudar agora, entre em contato! (Por exemplo, se todas as strings estiverem corretas, eu posso marcá-las como revisadas.)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Eu acredito que as estão corretas, acho que podemos aprová-las, e caso alguma não esteja totalmente correta, a comunidade pode corrigir depois. Acho que é melhor do que deixar a maior parte da página em inglês

Comment: Tem como voltar pro formato antigo de perguntas? O fundo nessa cor acinzentada com os desenhos me incomoda profundamente. Outra coisa que me incomodou muito foi a barra de formatação: toda vez que clico em "nova pergunta" ela aparece. Mas eu já pedi pra ela sumir, não gostaria que isso fosse necessário fazer a cada nova pergunta!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky alguma previsão para colocar tudo em português? Aumentou a quantidade de perguntas que precisam ser fechadas. A SE ativar algo pela metade e deixar por tantos dias era surpreendente há algum tempo.

Comment: Hey @Maniero! Se você vir algumas strings em inglês, sinta-se à vontade para traduzi-las em pt.traducir.win. Eu aprovei todas as strings que tinham uma única tradução. Se você vir strings em inglês, significa que ainda não foram traduzidas.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky acabei de fazer mais algumas traduções. Pode dar uma olhada e aprovar? Acho que podem ser melhoradas, mas do jeito que está não tem como ficar, fiz um pouco correndo. Mais tarde volto e faço mais algumas. Queria entender depois porque tantas pessoas passaram por aqui e não complementaram a tradução...

Comment: @Dherik O que eu não entendo é o procedimento da SE. O Nicolas tinha me mandado por email um CSV com as strings e eu devolvi o arquivo traduzido, e **achei que ali já tinha todas as strings**. Mas pelo jeito não tinha, ou então não cadastraram tudo, ou teve algum outro problema... Sei lá, é muito cômodo pra empresa lançar algo pela metade e jogar a culpa na comunidade que não traduziu algo que eu achei que já estava traduzido...

Comment: @hkotsubo ficou claro que teve alguma confusão, imaginei algo na linha do que falou mesmo. Mas problemas acontecem e precisam ser resolvidos. Fiquei bem decepcionado em perceber agora que vários dias passaram e ninguém foi lá conferir no traducir o que houve e (re)fazer a tradução. Muita gente viu o problema e não fez nada, algo simples e rápido de fazer, que afeta bastante o site. Os motivos para terem ignorado eu deixo que cada um pense por si só, mas eu imagino vários.

Comment: Houve um mal-entendido. Eu adicionei todas as strings que o hkotsubo me enviou e aprovou todas as sugestões do Dherik. Muito obrigado! Novas traduções devem ser publicadas com a próxima compilação.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, foram publicadas! Bem melhor agora. Depois vou dar uma revisada, achei alguns detalhes para acertar e pequenos trechos sem traduzir.

Comment: Relacionado: ["Qual o critério da página de fazer pergunta para determinar a qualidade de uma pergunta? É possível melhorá-lo?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8717/112052)

Answer (score 6):

Tem como reverter a página de perguntas para a original? Como se fosse um opt-out?

Além de que eu a acho desnecessariamente poluída com seus desenhos bonitinhos atrás e com um fundo de cor contrastante com o corpo principal de escrita/*live preview*, ela não me traz informação útil *alguma* quando estou colocando as tags:

[image: cadê o bolão com as informações de como publicar?]

Após preencher a tag e clicar no botão de "revisão", sou jogado para cima para receber a inútil mensagem de que "está tudo bem":

[image: sim, e daí? eu já sabia que tava tudo bem, agora cadê meu botão de publicar?]

No meu primeiro teste que eu fiz, cliquei em "Revisar publicação" com um título super descritivo: "a". Após clicar em revisar, fui jogado para o título, onde o sistema me informou corretamente que faltavam 14 caracteres no título. Mesmo não alterando *nada* no título, após baixar a tela novamente, sou agraciado com o botão "Publique sua pergunta". Mas, e aí? O sistema não precisa revisar novamente para saber se eu fiz besteira não?

Aliás, como podem ver, minha ótima pergunta com parágrafos super explicativos e um poderoso e imponente e significativo título estão de acordo com o que essa nova tela requer.

Então, por favor, tem como existir um opt-out para tentar manter a sanidade mental e experiência de uso?

Comment: É bater em tecla morta, eu fiz um baita texto https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8247/3635, basicamente o q o  hkotsubo respondeu ali foi a mesma coisa, só com mais detalhes, ainda sim preferiram a resposta dele, ok, nem faz diferença mesmo, a questão é, a SE muda a pagina de pergunta, muda o bloquote, muda o estilo visual de uma coisa ou outra, e parece que tudo isso é pra dizer que estão fazendo algo, como se o prefeito de uma cidade pintasse as comunidades carentes com cores alegres, mas ainda sim não fizesse o que as pessoas necessitam.