# Passo "3. Mostre algum código" em Fazer uma Pergunta

Tags: debate, perguntas

Quando clicamos em "Fazer uma pergunta" a seguinte tela de ajuda aparece:

[image: Tela de ajuda]

Em que o passo 3 é o seguinte "Mostre **algum** código".

Mas creio que não é algum código que é necessário, mas sim algo específico como o [mcve].

Vejo que muitos usuários novos simplesmente fazem um copiar e colar de algum código da internet para criar a pergunta, mas muitas vezes não tem relação com o problema ou parece que o AP nem tentou...

Acham que seria válido alterar este texto para outra frase?
Como por exemplo "Mostre o seu código" ou "Mostre um código de exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável"?

Obs.: O texto da observação explica direitinho, que deveria ser um [mcve] na pergunta. Mas esta janela está minimizada e muitas vezes pode passar sem ser lida. E os usuários simplesmente interpretarem como inserir "algum" código.

Comment: Acho que a sugestão do "Mostre o seu código" fica melhor mesmo. Provavelmente fui eu que fiz a tradução. Algumas traduções precisam de melhoria, acabei fazendo correndo na época pois esta parte da pergunta ficou mais de 1 semana com metade das descrições em inglês e eu achei um tanto quanto urgente solucionar isto logo. Acabei mantendo uma tradução mais próxima do inglês, que no caso aí deve ser `Show some code`. Se quiser, você mesmo consegue arrumar e aguardar a aprovação: https://pt.traducir.win

Comment: É válido, mas a SE passou um tempo monumental pensando nisso, eles tem um departo de UX. Então provavelmente acharam que não era necessário. Pouco a pouco eles tem escondido referências ao MCVE e outras informações que ajudam o usuário se dar bem no site, obrigando as pessoas terem que ficar informando a pessoa de algo que o sistema poderia fazer, e cansa todo mundo e aí param de fazer e cria um círculo vicioso. Tem várias postagens mostrando que toda essa página precisa de muito mais informação, e até mais interação com o usuário para tentar produzir um conteúdo melhor.

Comment: Como o original em inglês é "Show some code", vou esperar a opinião das pessoas para sugerir outra forma.

Comment: @Maniero Quando anunciaram que seria o Wizard, pensei que era um Wizard beta que uma vez vi. Que cada passo tinha um manual completo e moderno explicando o que deveria ser feito numa primeira pergunta do usuário, com exemplos. Começando pelo título e assim por diante. Quando lançaram este wizard, confesso que me decepcionei...

Comment: Todo mundo achou. Alguém lá determinou que o Wizard não era bom. Provavelmente criava dificuldade para alguém postar algo e desistia, então sem o Wizard a pessoa posta, é fechado, negativo e a pessoa desiste do mesmo jeito, mas agora com mais frustração que antes.

Comment: Relacionados (mostrando como esse wizard não tem nada de wizard): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8246/112052 | https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8271/112052 - Enfim, acho que somente mudar o texto não ajudará tanto porque a interface não obriga de fato a colocar um código (na verdade nem faz o usuário pensar a respeito, dado que é um texto escondido no canto que desaparece no passo 2 (veja as respostas dos links indicados), vide a quantidade de perguntas sem código que continuam aparecendo)

Comment: @danieltakeshi, Se quer dizer que aquele "some" é um adverbio de intensidade e não um pronome eu concordo com você. A tradução pode ser "Mostre um pouco de código".