# Por que a porcentagem de perguntas fechadas no Stack Overflow em Português é duas vezes maior que em outros Stack Overflows?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Olhando para as [estatísticas de porcentagem de fechamento de perguntas nos sites da rede Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346725/178179), vejo que no Stack Overflow o percentual de fechamento de perguntas em português (~ 37%) é duas vezes maior que em outros Stack Overflows. Existem razões para isso? Apenas curioso.

Comment: Questão da qualidade das perguntas. Para você na sua lista de perguntas na home do site aparecem apenas as perguntas respondíveis ou recuperáveis, as perguntas mal feitas(que são maioria) lhe ficam ocultas, então se pegar a sua lista de perguntas normalizadas(que já nasceram boas ou então foram aprimorada até ficarem boas) e olhar para essa lista de porcentagem de fechamentos parece que é um número elevado. Se pegar a lista de perguntas que eu vejo é de chorar, pois a porcentagem esta baixa, tem muita coisa que deixamos passar e que ou ficam eternamente em aberto ou geram respostas absurdas..

Answer (score 16):

## Não conheço os outros sites

Eu não posso responder porque não frequento os outros sites. Vejo um pouco o site em inglês e encontro muita coisa ruim aberta, em geral há negativação e acaba sendo removido, mas não fechado, nas outras línguas não faço a menor ideia. Aparentemente falta gente interessada em fechar ou as que estão interessadas não possuem privilégio, ou ainda não querem ver seu nome vinculado ao fechamento e o negativo é anônimo.

## Como é aqui

Eu sei que aqui tem uma qualidade muito baixa de perguntas.

É comum as perguntas não terem todas informações necessárias, hora falta o código, hora falta o erro, hora falta explicação de como reproduzir, ou simplesmente o texto é confuso demais.

Há um índice de escolaridade muito baixo no Brasil, o principal país da língua, e há um incentivo para pessoas que mal sabem escrever começarem programar porque isso dá futuro.

Há muitos casos que as perguntas são só códigos gerais cheio de erros que a pessoa pede para alguém resolver todos para ele, o que costuma ser ampla, mas alguns casos nem o código tem o que é um enunciado de problema, muitas vezes um exercício escolar. Há uma quantidade tão grande de casos assim que temos um motivo de fechamento próprio para isso. As pessoas acham que simplesmente podem colocar o que querem (muitas vezes de forma bem ruim) e [alguém fará o código](https://xkcd.com/386/) para ela.

Lamento dizer isso mas vivemos em país que muitas pessoas são corruptas por natureza (tem muita gente que não é), então elas nem entendem que trapacear na escola ou trabalho também é corrupção, elas entendem que só políticos que roubam dinheiro público é corrupto. Depois ela reclama que não tem oportunidades e é vítima da sociedade.

Sem falar que muitas perguntas na prática já foram respondidas, as pessoas nem tentam pesquisar (em alguns casos ela acha a que responde, mas ela quer que alguém altere o código dela, não basta ensinar como resolver). Em geral basta ler o que já existe que dará uma solução para a pessoa.

E também há muitas perguntas que é só erro de digitação, é impressionante a quantidade disso.

E nem fechamos quando a pessoa só não consegue interpretar a mensagem de erro bem óbvia, chega ser trágico o tipo de pergunta que aparece. Podemos dizer que são leigos tentando programar. E aceitamos bem perguntas bem básicas, o problema é justamente as perguntas complexas feitas por quem não sabe o básico.

De um ano pra cá as pessoas começaram postar 2 ou 3 vezes a mesma pergunta. È fechado, ela posta de novo para ver se desta vez não fecha, isso ajuda explicar o aumento na estatística também. No começo usávamos o motivo da duplicata, mas como é um repetição idêntica, ou quase, é não duplicata, agora fechamos pelo mesmo motivo de antes, assim provavelmente a pergunta será removida.

## Moderação

Junta-se ao fato de ter moderadores que se preocupam com isso e não deixam passar esse tipo de coisa.

Não sei de todos os sites, mas no SOen vejo que se tornou impossível para os moderadores cuidarem de fato do site, e a comunidade também não tem feito o trabalho de curadoria que era feito no começo, porque os bons usuários não tem tempo para para isso.

Há um pouco esse problema aqui, a comunidade de fato hoje é composta de poucos usuários e as tarefas de moderação ficam prejudicadas, a maioria dos usuários ou só querem postas perguntas e respostas ou são hit and run, e os que ajudavam moderar bem desistiram do site. Quando essas pessoas eram ativas e moderavam era possível salvar muita coisa hoje é raro fazerem algo e o que foi fechado tende ficar fechado para sempre, no passado reabria.

Esse parágrafo está sendo colocado depois. Eu fiquei observando e conclui uma outra coisa que andou acontecendo aqui. É mais uma opinião que uma certeza. Brasileiro, infelizmente, tem adotado demais WhatsApp, e eventualmente Telegram para tudo na vida. Isso é um enorme erro, mas não temos como combater isso. Eventualmente usam Facebook também. Nesses ambientes as pessoas estão acostumadas a querer uma "ajudinha" (que acaba sendo fazer tudo para ela), dicas gerais, opiniões, e elas querem interagir, choramingar, elas fazem de tudo, menos seguir as regras do site.

## Difícil reabrir

As pessoas que perguntam raramente conseguem melhorar suas questões por conta própria, não é que elas não sabem programar, até pode ser um pouco, mas elas tentam fazer coisas complexas quando não sabem o básico o que torna um pesadelo tentar ajudar.

Mas ainda não é só isso, elas costumam ter dificuldade de entender textos, seguir instruções, é comum terem preguiça de ler o que lhe é passado, ou simplesmente acreditam que a regras devem ser adaptadas a elas e não o contrário.

## Conclusão

Eu achei que estaríamos em primeiro lugar, foi surpreendente ter tantos outros sites na frente. E pra ser sincero se quiséssemos muita qualidade nós seríamos primeiro lugar, se decidirmos ser um pouco mais rígidos dá para fechar 70 ou 80% das perguntas, em alguns períodos talvez passe de 90%. Quase todas as perguntas postadas hoje em dia aqui não ajudam outras pessoas, é um helpdesk individual, o que nunca foi o objetivo do site.

Note que piorou, não era uma porcentagem tão alta antes, é o que eu falei, piorou muito o nível das perguntas, todos os usuários falam disso, até os que são contra os fechamentos.

Respondi por ter vindo de usuário que não costuma frequentar aqui e tera dificuldade de buscar, mas o assunto já foi discutido antes algumas vezes.

E eu fico em uma situação de parar de estancar todos os vazamentos porque hoje são muitos e não tem gente suficiente para parar tanta água rolando, ou começar ser até mais rígido, ir mais no automático para dar conta de tanto de trabalho, mesmo fechando eventualmente o que não deve para deixar a comunidade reabrir se for pertinente, ou seja, combater fogo com fogo.

Comment: Não comentei nada antes pq todos os pontos essenciais foram cobertos na resposta, mas após pensar um pouco mais, achei importante deixar registrado aqui que eu como ♦ e principalmente como usuário do SOpt desde a sua criação, estou integralmente de acordo com essa resposta.

Comment: Acabei por colocar um quadro do xkcd em um ponto que achei fundamentalmente interessante na sua resposta. Se por acaso esse pequeno "easter egg" atrapalhar a atmosfera desejada na resposta, peço desculpas, mas achei na hora da edição como um acréscimo válido

Answer (score 11):

Olha, não faz muito tempo que utilizo esse site, mas acredito que isso se da ao fato de alguns pontos além dos já citados nas outras respostas acima...

A página onde as pessoas fazem perguntas não é intuitiva, só tem um campo de título, descrição e tags e isso é muito "fraco" pra mim.
Eu acredito que poucas pessoas leem as regras do site e fazem o tour... Elas vão lá de cara e fazem suas perguntas.

O fato é que essa página não entrega a devida "validação" que a comunidade espera... Mas, na minha visão, deveriam se ter "tipos" de perguntas e conforme o usuário as seleciona, os campos da página deveriam se adaptar... Esses campos deveriam ser regido pelos moderadores.

Exemplo: Ter um campo aonde ele é obrigado a informar dados da sua plataforma, outro para pedaços do seu código e assim por diante.

Porque o cara que esta fazendo a pergunta não leu nada, não entende como o site funciona e acredita que as pessoas vão conseguir ajuda-lo só com aquilo que ele escreveu lá...

Fora que essa questão de fechar as perguntas me parece que ocorre mais nas tags relacionadas a programação, quando é uma pergunta relacionada a banco de dados, passa muita coisa absurda e ninguém fecha (isso eu não entendo).

Comment: De fato, a página de fazer pergunta é muito ruim, conforme discutido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8246/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8271/112052). Infelizmente a Stack Overflow (empresa) escolheu ignorar quaisquer pedidos de melhoria, deixando para nós o ingrato trabalho de instruir e ajudar as centenas de pessoas que não conseguem fazer uma pergunta clara...

Comment: Sim, isso é literalmente dar arma na mão de macaco. Parece um e-mail on a pessoa digita o assunto e bota qualquer coisa no corpo e deu. Daí depois que a pergunta é fechada ninguém vai atrás pra ver o que errou e ajusta a pergunta... Concorda comigo que isso deveria ser feito antes?

Comment: Sim, o sistema deveria ser mais inteligente e guiar o usuário antes, durante e depois de fazer uma pergunta, algo parecido com [isso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803). Infelizmente, coisas assim nunca são implementadas...

Comment: Você esta a pouco tempo no site e incrivelmente notou o problema que muitos participantes com mais tempo não compreendem e insistem em culpar outras coisas, como culpar moderadores. Parabéns, você resumiu bem o problema e demonstrou ter interesse em visar e buscar a origem ao invés de vivenciar a ideia de culpar as pessoas que estão fazendo o máximo aqui voluntariamente para melhorar a qualidade do conteúdo +1

Comment: @BrunoWarmling sobre certas coisas não serem fechadas, é que realmente não damos conta de ver tudo. O problema é que o site foi projetado para um público alvo, e quem cuida da empresa atualmente está valorizando outro púbico alvo que em nada tem a ver com o propósito original. Aí coisas que uma comunidade saudável naturalmente fecharia, acabam sobrando pra moderação. Aí não tem como conseguir ver tudo. Passa MUITA coisa inadequada. Uma resposta válida para a pergunta seria "porque a moderação não dá conta de ver tudo, senão seriam umas cinco a dez vezes mais".

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que o nível das perguntas influenciam. Mas nada relacionado a fatores externos, etc. Talvez também pelo motivo dos moderadores BR serem mais rigorosos ou os moderadores de outros países terem menos tempo para estarem tão ativos no site, serem mais presentes. Talvez os moderadores BR se preocupem mais com a qualidade do conteúdo.

Mas é somente minha opinião. Não podemos afirmar muita coisa sem mais amostras de dados disponíveis.