# Como moderar o SOpt?

Tags: debate, comunidade, moderação

Primeiro farei um resumo do estado que estamos, no fim verão onde eu quero chegar. Este é a primeira parte de algo que desejo fazer, o próximo texto não será direcionado à comunidade, mas para ela avaliar. Este depende da opinião de vocês que usam o site, que elegeram a moderação, quem sente as dores do site.

## Stack Overflow

Em 2008 surge o Stack Overflow, algo que foi um fenômeno improvável, era algo fantástico, que todo mundo precisava, bom demais, era revolucionário sem inovar tanto assim, funcionava muito bem mesmo quando tentava sair do trilho, e sempre que algo ruim acontecia tinha uma solução rápida. Por muito tempo era claro que se queria qualidade, e principalmente [evitar o problema da cauda longa](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Todas as ações eram claras nesse sentido. Realmente incrível estar entre os 30 ou 50 sites mais visitados do mundo em um nicho (chega estar entre os 20 mais do Brasil!), principalmente se ver eventos, postagens, vídeos sobre o tema que tem por aí e tem audiência ridiculamente baixa.

[Em 2013 ganhamos a versão em português](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) após alguns anos em gestação. Em algum momento perto disso, provavelmente um pouco antes, que nem todos perceberam claramente, houve um posicionamento diferente da empresa e a busca pela qualidade, de resolver problemas, propor ferramentas para melhor atingir o resultado esperado, tudo isso foi ficando em segundo plano. A SE sempre negou isso, mas é percepção de muitos dos que estão engajados no site. Não vou nem entrar em algumas coisas que colocaram em primeiro plano porque não vai resolver.

## Qualidade

A SE nunca deixou o discurso de busca da qualidade, o que faz a comunidade ficar atônita, gera conflitos entre a empresa e na própria comunidade, porque dá margem para dois lados muitos distintos ficarem sempre se digladiando, não é claro qual é o caminho.

E a SE não vem investindo mais em ferramentas boas para melhorar a moderação que está cada vez mais complicada de fazer. Precisa melhorar muito. O SO surgiu em uma época diferente do mundo, a expectativa agora é de softwares com UX muito melhor do que era antes, em geral com algum nível de inteligência artificial. Não é que seja zero, mas a demanda é semrpe mais rápida que a resposta, muito mais.

A equipe de engenheiros responsáveis é notável e já se tornou lendária (faço minha parte para aumentar essa lenda em *posts* e palestras, uso o SO como *case* para mostrar como "os outros" fazem errado). Já a "equipe" de UX é uma piada, mas não sei se é diferente de outras equipes disso, que já ando considerando uma "profissão de charlatanismo" de tantos erros que essas pessoas cometem.

Mesmo com uma mudança nos últimos meses depois de um marco sério, a imagem da empresa está abalada, o novo CEO claramente quer uma direção, que pode ser legítima, mas  não bate com a busca da qualidade - e não há mais condições de investir pesado nas ferramentas para combater os problemas atuais da rede. Na verdade, a própria equipe geral da SE parece não ter mais a mesma vontade que tinha. Não é que não tenham vontade mais, mas ela é diferente, a gente via que todos se envolviam nos problemas do jeito que a comunidade precisava. Quero deixar claro que isso é problema da empresa e não dos funcionários. Não vou me aprofundar porque não é a questão.

O problema se dá na comunidade porque não conseguimos mais fazer o que dá para fazer. Especialmente no SOpt, não sei se tanto em outras comunidades. Por dados que vemos por aí não parece que somos o pior caso, mas não somos o melhor. Somos o pior entre os SOs (as comunidades específicas de programação nas 5 línguas disponíveis) - tem *link* abaixo.

## Cultura

Não falarei de novo de forma intensa sobre os problemas da cultura brasileira. E não parece tão diferente em outros países de língua portuguesa. Isso talvez justificaria um pouco um problema maior, mas sei que o mesmo problema que faz precisar de uma língua específica para se comunicar talvez seja o que não deixe o formato ser útil.

Não quero falar muitos dos outros SOs para não parecer ignorância ou xenofobia, mas até onde sei outros países que tem SOs na sua língua que não o inglês também não tem cultura que favorece tanto assim o formato. Sei que no Brasil temos um certo desprezo pela ciência, exceto por um grupo pequeno que acaba sendo uma "elite".

Por um lado, buscar o resultado "elite" tem seus méritos porque o nível sempre deveria ser colocado um pouco acima para fazer todos, um dia, serem elite. Por outro aceitar o resultado básico tem seu mérito por tornar mais acessível, embora coloque o nível cada vez mais baixo e isso tem uma consequência ruim para a sociedade. E esse tipo de atitude explica muito porque o país (Brasil, mas não são diferentes dos demais que falam português, basta comparar os países europeus por exemplo) tem problemas estruturais que impedem acabar com a pobreza e algumas pessoas acham que isso é bom, mesmo tendo a melhor das intenções e achando que não tem esse problema.

## SOpt

Começamos bem. Com alguns problemas, claro, mas nada grave. Desde o princípio teve discussões sobre a qualidade, eu sempre me posicionei para manter mais as perguntas, mas sempre procurando qualidade.

Havia uma grande quantidade de pessoas que entendiam o site e faziam tudo para buscar a qualidade, o que permitia aceitar muita coisa que nem era tão boa, afinal tinha boa chance de se tornar boa.

O tempo foi passando e essas pessoas começaram cansar e muitas deixaram o site. Pelo que conversei com várias o motivo era ter que ficar arrumando tanto problema. Embora o site incentive e tenha ferramentas que ajude lidar com os problemas eles estavam cada vez maiores, em muitos casos a ajuda acabava sendo inócua, dava muito trabalho, gerava discussões e nenhum resultado positivo.

Algumas pessoas disfarçam um pouco falando em parte isso e em parte dizem que estão com muito trabalho, mas que nunca mais passa ter pouco trabalho para voltar ser ativo no site. As pessoas tem dificuldade de admitir o que realmente pensam.

A quantidade de problemas aumentava, tornava-se mais difícil consertar tudo e parecia que estávamos enxugando gelo, quanto mais se arrumava mais problema chegava.

As perguntas de qualidade começaram minguar, começou ficar menos gratificante responder, e menos ainda ficar tentando salvar perguntas ruins. **As ferramentas não ajudam**, as pessoas começaram fazer um trabalho quase robótico para pouca melhoria. Todo mundo que eu conversei e que desistiu do site parcial ou totalmente, em maior ou menor grau, não aguentavam mais ficar enxugando esse gelo.

Acabou que muito trabalho sobrou para poucas pessoas restantes, o que foi cansando mais.

Quero deixar claro que não estou cobrando mais trabalho de qualquer pessoa, ainda que em dado momento possa parecer que seja isso.

É um fardo muito grande poucas pessoas tendo que lidar com tantos problemas. É pior, porque as pessoas que tem chego ao site são cada vez mais, me desculpe por dizer isso, não quero ofender ninguém, mas qualquer um nota um nível baixo de educação, em todos sentidos, fazendo com que elas não consigam se comunicar, interpretar textos, seguir instruções, resolver problemas em nível simples, embora parte do problema seja outro, e demonstram que não estão interessadas em ajudar os outros as ajudarem.

Falando um português bem claro, passamos ser babá dessas pessoas. E não é incomum haver atritos, sermos ofendidos por elas. Mesmo quando há alguma discussão "saudável" é desgastante ter que fazer isso de novo e de novo e de novo.

A SE parece acreditar que as pessoas farão um trabalho melhor e por isso o mecanismo não ajuda. E esse é um problema de UX, está ignorando esse fardo, a falta de gratificação em fazer esse trabalho sem sentido.

Eu noto isso em todos os sites da rede que vou, mas não posso falar muito em detalhe de todos.

## Comunidade

Posso falar do SOpt e aqui falta comunidade.

Teve época que achei que faltava moderação, mas ficou claro que não é o caso. Aqui apenas um moderador dá conta das tarefas exclusivas de diamante, ainda que seja bom distribuir e ter outras pessoas para ajudar em decisões.

O que falta são pessoas com disposição (e capacidade) para ficar editando tudo da forma correta, comentar sem parar até que uma pergunta fique boa ou uma resposta fique certa, ou votar de todas formas possíveis, *up*, *down*, *close*, *reopen*, etc. Isso todo mundo pode fazer (alguns casos precisam de 3 ou 10K), mas só algumas fazem apropriadamente.

As pessoas estão fazendo pouco isso. Eu entendo. Eu mesmo, ainda que seja quem mais faz, faço menos do que demanda. Não estou cobrando vocês.

Não é fácil. Essa semana eu tive um trabalhão com um fechamento que fiz e isso acontece semrpe que tento ajudar um pouco mais. Também vi um caso de uma pessoa que respondeu e prejudicava o AP e outras pessoas ingênuas que fossem ler lá, e mesmo várias pessoas alertando para isso o AR insistiu que ela só iria responder o problema perguntado e não se importou que aquilo fosse errado e causasse prejuízo. Esse tipo de coisa é muito comum. Tem muita gente sem compromisso com a qualidade.

E o pior, se você comenta algo que desagrade a pessoa, se você negativa algo errado você pode sofrer retaliação. Não necessariamente negativos, mas retirada de positivos, a pessoa evitar dar positivos em você. Coisas que a SE nem sempre acha que é retaliação. Então todo mundo começa fazer isso, fica menos gratificante, e todo perdem. O site deixa de ser o que era há 10 anos atrás. Eu cansei de sofrer retaliações.

Algumas pessoas se especializaram em ir no limite das regras e perseguir quem negativa algo ruim dela. Tem pessoas que eu não negativo há muito tempo mesmo tendo postado várias coisas ruins porque eu sei que ela vai retaliar. Isso é péssimo para o site. A comunidade nem pode fazer o que precisa.

A questão é até bem mais séria, mas é outra discussão. É algo que a SE não parece disposta cuidar, incorporou como parte do processo.

Mas tem lado bom, a comunidade tem ajudado em muita coisa. Fizemos algumas iniciativas para tentar dar mais informação já que a ferramenta não ajuda. Não sei se todas são boas, mas fizemos algo.

- [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/101)
- [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/101)
- [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/101)
- [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/101)
- [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/101)
- [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101)
- [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)

Usamos de várias formas. Não funciona. As pessoas ignoram ou não conseguem entender. Podem não ser boas, afinal o resultado é pífio.

Ainda tem outros problemas como alguns usuários que fazem tudo para dificultar, usam o site do jeito que acham que deve ser, sem discutir, mesmo causando problemas, mesmo sendo contra o que foi decidido.

Ou você impõe a força de vez ou cede e deixa acontecer e as pessoas que assumam as consequências, mesmo que elas não percebam que haverá problemas.

Algumas pessoas só querem responder sem compromisso, e algumas, até porque acham que vão ganhar algo com isso, ou pra atingir um gosto pessoal, querem fazer o que deveriam estar fazendo em redes sociais, não em um site de Q&A.

É terrível que boa parte dos usuários, e nem vou chamar de comunidade, que só pensam em si, só no seu problema, na sua necessidade, que não se importem em ajudar outras pessoas de forma real, efetiva, verdadeira e necessária. É pior quando você tenta mostrar isso recebe um desprezo ou rejeição muitas vezes agressivas.

Sei que algumas pessoas podem pensar isso de mim, mas meu objetivo sempre foi o melhor para todos, nunca pelo individuo, tem histórico por todo meta e chat, para o bem ou para o mal.

Muitos usuários, cada vez mais a maioria, não querem um site de Q&A como ele foi concebido. A questão é saber se devemos ceder ao que eles querem ou forçar o que deveria ser o site. Se forçar ele fica quase inviável, é assintonia total. Mas não é o que eu estou perguntando, porque forçar ser um site de Q&A para quem não quer isso é um trabalho muito pesado.

Cansa eu propor diversas coisas pra tentar melhorar algo e ter pouca adesão, não ver empolgação das pessoas. Eu entendo isso, não estou dizendo que as pessoas estão erradas. Até ser contra essas propostas poderia ser melhor. Agora, propor coisas pra eu ficar fazendo sozinho não é agradável.

Só estou colocando isso por algumas pessoas que ainda querem algo melhor. Sem elas eu já teria tomado uma decisão sem recorrer a esta postagem.

## Moderação

Quando fui eleito, disse que moderador tem que fazer o que a comunidade falha. Algumas coisas o moderador é obrigado porque a comunidade não pode fazer, as vezes por falha da ferramenta (exemplo é a comunidade poder remover uma resposta e não poder transformar em comentário exigindo um moderador).

Não queria fechar tanta coisa, mas muita coisa merece ser fechada. A comunidade não fechando rápido alguém tem que fazer.

E se não fizer rápido alguém responde algo que não dava para responder ou que incentiva atitudes ruins. Em geral são respostas ruins que costumam ser aceitas e podem ou não ter negativos. Resposta positivada deixou de ser sinal de qualidade aqui faz tempo, aceitação nunca foi um bom sinal, por isso o site não deveria valorizar isso há muito tempo (o SOen começou fazer algo).

Algumas pessoas fazem por ingenuidade, por não conhecer o site, outras fazem de propósito, porque querem pontos a qualquer custo. Algumas talvez por não concordarem que algo deva ser fechado mesmo tendo problemas.

Fica uma coisa ruim porque as pessoas usam esses casos para justificar outros erros. Pegam essa atitude para fazerem erros também.

Sempre aparecem pessoas dizendo que devemos fechar menos, que devemos comentar mais, editar para melhorar, mas elas somem logo depois, só os outros que devem fazer. Isso gera atrito, desgaste e nenhuma solução. Dão esmola com a carteira dos outros.

A comunidade cansou de fazer algo que não gera bom resultado, que fica pela metade, que lhe traz problemas, de forma agressiva ou não, mas mesmo com boa intenção costuma dar muito trabalho para algo que não é o objetivo do site.

Hoje **o site tem muito ruído**.

As pessoas passaram a não ter orgulho mais do que acontece aqui.

Elas já não conseguem moderar como deveriam por tudo o que eu falei antes. Preste atenção em tudo dito, não foi gratuito, cada ponto foi abordado por um motivo.

Os moderadores precisam fazer certas partes, por exemplo fechar muito.

Isso tornou-se um peso grande, dificulta fazer outras coisas, porque a carga de trabalho não é equilibrada. E tem muita coisa pra fechar.

Tem dia que precisa fechar mais de 80% das perguntas, ainda que não feche, e sabemos que mais de 90% nunca será reaberta. Pode gastar o tempo que quiser lá e não sairá algo bom. Não é produtivo, não é agradável.

Nem pioramos muito em vários itens diversos de fechamento. O que piorou muito é a pergunta que é só um enunciado, mesmo que disfarçado, e a pessoa quer que faça para ela. Alguns exemplos desses dias:

- [PDF C# Como Gerar Pdf .NETCore?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454985/101)
- [Agrupamento de dados distintos - SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455077/101)
- [Sistema de venda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455069/101)
- [Como capturar evento de minimizar APP em ionic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455176/101)
- [Como fazer a média entre 2 valores que foram gravados no mesmo segundo no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455164/101)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455189/101
- [Como fazer para cada usuario puxar a informação criada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455273/101)
- [me ajudem com uma prova? Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455324/101)
- [Criar um "questionário" em um site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455342/101)
- [Duvida com media em listas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455572/101)
- [Popular combobox com Django](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456130/101)

Eu não quero mais fechar perguntas, mas não vejo solução. Eu quero que seja mais fácil fazer todas tarefas, orientar melhor, quero que tenha menos perguntas com problemas, menos pessoas completamente sem noção e sem comprometimento com o que está fazendo, que aceitem que pessoas experientes no site, em programação e na vida, lhes orientem. Mas querer a maioria dessas coisas é utópico.

O *engine* do site poderia ajudar muito mais. [Fizemos uma brincadeira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/101), mas muita coisa ali na verdade é séria. Faríamos mais se soubéssemos que a SE implementaria mesmo que uma forma diferente boa parte delas. Não fazemos porque é perda de tempo.

Recentemente o SOpt vem sendo questionado se a moderação está fechando muitas perguntas ([Por que a porcentagem de perguntas fechadas no Stack Overflow em Português é duas vezes maior que em outros Stack Overflows?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8311/101) e [2019: moderação do site em números](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8115/101)). Não vejo como poderia ser diferente.

Mas não é agradável fazer isso. As pessoas são especialistas em fazer te sentir mal por fazer apenas o que é necessário. Você começa se questionar se vale a pena todo esse esforço e desgaste para tentar ajudar com algo que muita gente não quer e você ganha nada.

Não está fácil gastar tempo em algo que não resolve problema algum. Mas se não o fizer tudo fica pior, e aí o site caminhará rápido para **ser o Yahoo! Respostas**. Já está um pouco, temos muitas respostas de qualidade bem ruim, ensinando errado, até mesmo são usadas como desculpas pelo erro posterior (Ex.: a pessoa faz *query* com SQL Injection e diz que aprendeu aqui fazer assim, quase todas perguntas que tem *query* ultimamente tem esse problema e a maioria das respostas não fala nada sobre isso, é um enorme desserviço).

O SOpt já se tornou um repositório de soluções erradas e fonte de desensino. Mas tem uma quantidade de conteúdo bom, principalmente postado no começo, que se diga de passagem não é mais valorizado como era no passado, praticamente não tem votos mais em conteúdo antigo, não era assim, as pessoas sabiam aproveitar mais o repositório.

O que me segura aqui é que muitos querem algo melhor. Mas não são tão muitos assim. Eu só não vou dizer que já são minoria, porque essas pessoas fazem parte da comunidade e a maioria que quer que a qualidade vá para o ralo de vez não fazem parte, elas estão de passagem ou uma vez ou algumas vezes. Elas não sentirão as consequências, elas não se importam com o site. Elas têm seus motivos, seus interesses para isso, não ligam para o bem de todos, só querem sentir que fizeram algo ou obter uma "ajudinha", não importa a qualidade daquilo.

Se falta comunidade falta moderação. Não adianta por outras pessoas para moderar com poder de diamante se elas já fazem menos. Você vai tirar uma pessoa que tem algumas responsabilidades para ter outras mais, então ela provavelmente fará menos o que ela já não fazia tanto. Não adianta colocar alguém que deseja que se faça menos do que já se faz. Fazer menos eu sei fazer.

Não quero falar por outros moderadores, mas sinto que pensam pelo menos em parte semelhante a isso.

Já chego no ponto principal porque estou falando isso.

## Baixa qualidade

Ultimamente escutei de algumas pessoas que até não dá mais orgulho fazer parte do site, que se arrependeram de terem entrado porque não sabiam que isso se transformaria em um repositório de baixa qualidade, há quem quer ou tirou o nome do perfil.

Pra voltar ficar bom teria que remover muita coisa, mesmo positivada, e mesmo que a ideia fosse bem aceita nunca seria feito. Eu não faria, é muito trabalho, tinha que impedir de acontecer.

Não sei mais o que fazer e acho que não há como solucionar isso. Ajudaria se tivéssemos ferramentas muito superiores para fazer parte do trabalho repetitivo, se houvesse uma barreira para se perguntar, mas isso não vai acontecer. Nem sei se resolveria tanto assim, e precisaria acontecer bem antes para manter a comunidade grande e ativa, para não cansar as pessoas. Quem foi não volta mais.

Parte do motivo de eu estar aqui não existe mais, mas ainda tem algum motivo.

Não sei se vale a pena insistir na qualidade. Mas ainda o faço pra eu não desistir de vez.

O SOpt não está sendo o que foi projetado para ser, virou um *helpdesk*, que as pessoas acham que é igual Facebook ou grupo de WhatsApp (quem não é brasileiro talvez não saiba a praga que é isso, é o uso mais errado possível que uma ferramenta pode ter). Não é que as pessoas acham que aqui é um fórum, é muito pior.

## Minha dúvida

De forma alguma estou dizendo que não quero moderar mais, que não vou participar do site do jeito que sempre fiz.

Mas **o que acham se eu começar a não fazer tanto assim o que a comunidade deveria fazer e não faz? Se deixar rolar, mesmo que isso seja ruim para o site?**

Eu só estaria deixando o fluxo da comunidade, se ela quer baixa qualidade é o que terá. Penso em fazer um pouco o que eu disse na eleição, mas de forma um pouco diferente. Eu passaria a considerar que se a comunidade não vota para fechar então não é falha dela, é o que ela quer.

Se ela não negativa o que deveria, é o que ela quer. Mesmo que não negative porque não tem mais votos diários (eu preciso do dobro só para os negativos por dia, pelo menos em alguns dias).

Eu cansei também, queria *feedback* de vocês.

Pensem bem no que vão dizer e até se vão silenciar. O que for decidido, por mim, baseado no que disserem, mas não exatamente o que me disserem para fazer, terá consequências para o futuro do site e que não será fácil arrumar depois. E que fique claro, de um jeito ou de outro não é um bom futuro, só não sei o quanto eu devo influenciar para um lado ou para outro

Eu sei o que é bom para que o site seja sempre uma referência confiável e as pessoas que o usam da forma correta, mas isso está ficando contra o que é bom pra mim. Eu nem sei se eu conseguirei dissociar tão bem assim. Estou pedindo autorização para fazer o que **não será bom** para o site. Ainda que provavelmente eu ainda faria mais do que qualquer outra pessoa aqui. Não é que eu estou propondo negligenciar, deixar de fazer algo que outros fariam melhor, estou só dizendo para ser mais como a comunidade está fazendo e eu deixar de assumir a maior parte da responsabilidade. **Posso deixar o fluxo acontecer sem interferir tanto?**

Não estou perguntando o que você acha que é bom para o site, estou pensando em mim, mas isso afetará vocês, eu tenho que perguntar.

Quanto mais eu tento ajudar, mais tem atritos, e isso cansa. Se eu fizer mais o burocrático desgasta menos e minha validade fica maior. Temos usuários muito difíceis. Temos bons também, são essas pessoas que me fazem continuar aqui.

Não quero parecer arrogante, mas é o meu empenho (e também do Bacco) que anda reduzindo o ritmo da queda de qualidade, segurando para o site não afundar de vez. Não sei se deveria falar isso, mas [sei que o Bacco já faz um tempo que está bem mais cético que eu quanto ao futuro do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2096/101) e digo isso porque entende mais que eu entendia que não tem muito mais o que fazer, eu sempre tive alguma esperança que obviamente perdi agora.

Claro que a comunidade tem um papel também, não estou dizendo que somos os únicos fazendo algo, mas acabamos tendo um papel importante por força do diamante, que nos foi confiado por uma boa quantidade de usuários engajados. Acho que todos enxergam que pelo poder do diamante e atuação diária resolvemos rápido muitos problemas.

Se eu mudar, provavelmente mudará a atitude de outras pessoas, algumas desistirão do site, algumas adorarão e farão a festa que sempre quiseram. Claro que se a comunidade não aceitar isso e mesmo que eu mude e elas tomarem essa responsabilidade, aí eu mesmo posso rever minha postura, só não quero ficar com grande parte do fardo. Mas se piorar duvido que tenha volta.

Eu nem sei o quanto conseguirei manter-me um pouco mais afastado que eu estou propondo pra mim mesmo. Eu não sei se serei 8 ou 80 com isso e aí teria que fazer uma opção mais radical, desistindo da ideia ou do site, mas isso é só especulação.

**Aceito todo tipo de sugestão, crítica, ou o que for**, desde que seja construtivo e entenda o que estou dizendo. Não é tudo que será acatado automaticamente ou está determinado quando colocarei em prática.

Eu não sei se consegui ser claro. Só, por favor, não venha desvirtuar a conversa com assuntos que não dizem respeito ao assunto do *post*.

Pena que muitas pessoas que poderiam falar algo bom desistiram do site ou cansaram e acham que nem vale falar algo, sei que a repercussão disto será pequena, é o que eu estou falando em todo o texto.

Me desculpe se isso parece um desabafo, mas achei importante por tudo que já expliquei. E me desculpe se agora estou pensando mais em mim do que na necessidade do site. Agradará alguns e não outros, não sei se agradará ou não a SE, ninguém sabe o que eles pensam de verdade, as mensagens são truncadas, cruzadas e ambíguas.

## Conclusão

Gosto de fazer paralelos e pergunto de que adianta fazer leis que exigem isolamento social, fechamento de estabelecimentos, uso de máscara, ainda que deveria exigir mais que isso, quando boa parte da população não faz isso, não há fiscalização? Deve-se fazer ou certo ou o que a população quer? Mesmo que seja a minoria, tem caso que só alguns indo contra é suficiente para todo plano sucumbir.

Eu cansei de protestar contra corrupção, falta de atendimento do estado onde ele é obrigado atender quando os políticos na sua totalidade não querem isso e boa parte da população também não quando afeta seu time (jogador) preferido na política. É a mesma coisa no SOpt.

Assim como governos cansaram de pedir para a população agir certo e ver que até quando parecem fazer o certo só estão disfarçando, eu cansei de enxugar gelo e jogando a toalha (governos jogaram nos últimos dias por aqui). Cansei se acumular *haters*.

[image: pessoa com máscara no queixo]

Que fique claro que continuarei ajudando o site, até onde eu puder.

Essa postagem é importante pra mim, até para quando um dia me cobrarem pela falta de qualidade, eu mostrar que eu fiz o que eu pude, que eu sempre tive o compromisso de fazer o que pude para tudo funcionar melhor. Se a qualidade está ruim não é porque eu quis ou não fiz minha parte, mas tudo tem um limite. Eu preciso ter uma justificativa e explicação porque eu não faço mais ainda. Eu tinha orgulho do SOpt, mas não do que ele se tornou. Eu não sou responsável por isso, aconteceu apesar do meu esforço. Pode ser até incompetência minha, mas não falta de vontade de fazer certo.

Sinto que a comunidade merece uma explicação e eu conquistei o direito de fazer algo assim pela posição que tenho tido por mais de 6 anos ou há quase 10 dependendo do critério.

Comment: Acho que é do interesse de todos, mas ao mesmo tempo é algo meu, então não sei se deveria colocar em destaque.

Comment: Não seja por isso, coloquei em destaque. Aproveito pra dizer que sou um dos que poderiam participar desse debate, mas não tenho certeza se vale a pena. Concordo com a premissa de que moderar o site como tem sido feito é insustentável.

Comment: @bfavaretto queria ouvir mais sobre isso, mas eu entendo :)

Comment: No momento prefiro me resguardar de uma opinião pois há muita coisa em jogo e há muito o que ser digerido. Por enquanto vou processar tudo o que foi escrito...⏳

Comment: @AugustoVasques espero que não fique todo mundo se resguardando :D

Comment: Eu tenho uma opinião sobre o rumo dá pagina. mas tenho que levar em conta minha inexperiência e o meu lugar, sou só mais usuário que mal completou um ano de uso da página. Não posso ser irresponsável, o problema é maior do que eu. Mas vou apresentar meu posicionamentos, só preciso pensar no que foi escrito e confrontar com o que vivi e aprendi aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: Se procura aprovação para a sua desistência, tem todo o meu apoio. Nem poderia não dá-lo, eu já desisti e nem tinha 1/100 do seu empenho. Admiro a sua persistência.

Comment: @ramaral obrigado pelo apoio, você é uma das pessoas que eu cito indiretamente :) Seu empenho é oque fazia valer um pouco a pena. Você tem toda minha compreensão por ter se afastado do site pelo menos em parte. Ainda ajuda aqui e ali, ajudou de forma absurdamente grande e boa antes, faz falta hoje. Nós tentamos, não é que eu demorei mais para perceber mais eu resisti um pouco mais. Cada um reduz ou se afasta de vez no seu tempo ou do jeito que acha melhor. Se eu não fosse moderador faria de forma silenciosa. Sei que mais pessoas vão abandonar o barco de vez.A SE não ajuda,os usuários só pioram

Comment: Algo que não sei se ficou claro que quero abordar aqui aqui é que **pretendo** entrar em menos perguntas do que costumo entrar (hoje em dia em quase todas) e nas que entrar talvez eu comece deixar sem fazer qualquer ação por dedicar o tempo necessário e ficar na dúvida ou achar que aquilo gerará muito trabalho adicional. Com isso muita coisa que eu fechava ficará aberta pelo menos por um tempo (estou começando olhar um pouco mais o que já tem votos depois para fechar o que a comunidade já indica ser ruim). Eu preciso gastar menos tempo no site, é só isso.

Comment: Eu acho que nós não possuímos o costume de "fazer ciência" na língua portuguesa, por isso, a maior parte dos possíveis usuários "bons" utilizam a comunidade internacional. Portanto, infelizmente o público alvo do SOpt está sendo usuários de menos qualidade mesmo.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim, acho que não devemos deixar desandar tudo. Eu olho muito mais as TAGs que eu sigo e possuo algum conhecimento, para acabar não fechando algo que não deveria ser fechado. A qualidade é importante e foi o tornou o SO na referência que é hoje, mas esta discussão da perda de qualidade está no SOen faz tempo e até lá não conseguiram resolver este problema, em grande parte pela falta de compromisso da empresa... Mas não sei como melhorar isso, mesmo com ferramentas, se o perfil da maioria dos novos usuários não se encaixa no que desejamos. É algo muito complexo

Comment: Pensamentos negativos atraem outros pensamentos negativos. Já positivos, outros positivos. Sei que está difícil e a maioria das pessoas está desanimando (inclusive eu), mas creio que um dos motivos de ter atraído muito gente no passado, era porque a comunidade era muito engajada e positiva, pelo menos para mim, parecia que contribuir ia ajudar a mudar o mundo. Os debates no Meta eram sempre de melhorias e pensamentos no futuro, que provavelmente iriam acontecer. Agora qualquer debate que ocorra sobre melhorias, provavelmente nem ocorrerá, por isso está ocorrendo esta morte lenta.

Comment: @danieltakeshi na verdade falta português e matemática básicos para as pessoas que andam perguntando. Els não conseguem mostrar que possuem pensamento lógico. Tem casos piores que muitos nem veem. Tem aumentado as advertências por uso erro no site, Em geral a pessoa tenta impor cada "lógica" no que estão fazendo que dá vontade de chorar. Uma coisa que percebi que obviamente que se você vai consertando tudo, fica mais difícil ficar ruim, mas sempre vinha alguém fazendo algo ruim. Reduzia a depreciação, mas não impedia.

Comment: Conforme todo mundo cansou de consertar acelerou o problema e agora todo mundo faz de forma ruim. Mas é impressionante como ensinar o certo (positivo) nunca dá resultado e o errado as pessoas aprendem muito facilmente, Impressiona como um começando fazer errado todo mundo começa fazer igual. Não é aleatório, as pessoas seguem um padrão conforme a época. Fiquei até muito curioso sociologicamente falando como ocorre esse fenômeno. A morte é iminente, está na UTI. E acho que já é tarde demais pra reverter, parece ser só vida vegetativa. Triste ter embarcado nessa.

Answer (score 10):

## Resposta curta

A decisão é única e exclusivamente sua. Eu não tenho o direito de exigir e nem pedir nada.

## Resposta longa

<sup>*Primeiro vou fazer uma longa análise da situação atual do site, e pode parecer que não tem nada a ver com a pergunta, mas espero que no final faça sentido.*</sup>

Mesmo não tendo criado uma conta logo no início do site, sempre gostei do Stack Overflow.

Uma das coisas que mais me atraiu nas primeiras vezes que visitei o site foram as respostas super detalhadas, que explicavam não só porque o código funciona, mas o conceito por trás daquilo (usando o super-clichê: não dava o peixe, ensinava a pescar - mais ainda, ensinava porque a vara X e o anzol Y funcionam melhor para o peixe A e não funcionam com o peixe B - para o qual deve ser usado outro tipo de equipamento).

Isso foi algo sem precedentes na época. Claro que antes até existiam essas informações, mas estavam espalhadas por milhares de blogs e fóruns, perdidas em meio a um monte de material duvidoso. E mesmo assim, era muito difícil encontrá-las.

Hoje praticamente todas as perguntas básicas e intermediárias (e várias avançadas) já foram respondidas, muitas por especialistas das respectivas áreas, e estão a um Google de distância. A ideia de servir como um **Repositório de conhecimento, com perguntas e respostas canônicas sobre programação** parecia ter realmente funcionado. Em qual outro site você pode ter sua dúvida respondida pelo próprio criador da linguagem/API/biblioteca/framework? (*aqui estou falando mais do SOen, que tem várias figurinhas famosas que efetivamente respondem*).

E todo o *modus operandi* do site era pensando no sentido de gerar e manter este repositório: deixar que qualquer um edite a pergunta, para deixá-la em um formato que sirva para qualquer outra pessoa que tenha o mesmo problema no futuro (e que não sirva apenas para o autor da pergunta). Deixar um título que seja fácil de ser encontrado por mecanismos de busca (por isso quase sempre achamos o que queremos, está tudo realmente a um Google de distância). Marcar perguntas como duplicadas, pois não precisamos, por exemplo, de [várias perguntas sobre como comparar strings em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/3905?lq=1), quando [apenas uma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/112052) que já explica isso em detalhes é o suficiente. Deixar uma resposta que não só resolva o problema específico da pessoa, mas que vá um pouco além e "ensine a pescar".

Mas parece que boa parte disso se perdeu. Muita, mas muita gente mesmo, não se preocupa com nada disso. Quem pergunta, só quer seu problema resolvido de qualquer jeito, escrevendo títulos genéricos que são péssimos para indexação ("Problema em [linguagem]", "Me ajudem"), só colocam enunciados e querem que façam tudo para ela, ou colocam um código que "não funciona", sem dizer o que ele deveria fazer. Quem responde, só se preocupa em fazer qualquer gambiarra que "resolva" o problema, sem se preocupar se o código é ruim, se está ensinando algo "errado" que não vai ajudar a pessoa no futuro.

Ainda usando a analogia do clichê da pesca: a pessoa diz que está tentando usar um taco de beisebol para pescar e diz que "não estou conseguindo, me ajudem". Em vez de responder "use uma vara e um anzol, o taco não é o ideal por motivos X, Y e Z, etc", as pessoas preferem sugerir métodos esdrúxulos ("espere o peixe chegar perto para acertá-lo", "pegue uma lixa e transforme o taco em uma lança, ficará mais fácil"), com a desculpa de que "só me baseei no código que o usuário forneceu". **NÃO!!** Se o código é ruim, se a pessoa está tentando do jeito errado/mais difícil, mostre que ela está errada (explicando o motivo, de preferência) e corrija o código. A menos, é claro, que ela tenha um motivo **muito** forte para não usar vara e anzol, mas esta restrição deveria estar na pergunta (e quase nunca está - na verdade quase nunca existe tal restrição). E o mesmo vale para casos em que a pessoa está usando vara e anzol do jeito errado: muita gente prefere insistir no erro e sugerir gambiarras em vez de mostrar a forma correta de usar.

> *Só pra constar que "código ruim" não é algo "maléfico" em si, pois todos já fomos iniciantes um dia e com certeza fizemos códigos horríveis no começo - eu fiz vários, tenho até vergonha. O que não pode acontecer é responder com código igualmente ruim sem mencionar o fato de que ele é ruim - se não quer sugerir algo melhor, ao menos **mencione** que aquilo não é bom. Um dos problemas é que vejo muita gente apresentar o código ruim como se fosse uma alternativa perfeitamente válida, sem ao menos sinalizar que existem formas melhores.*
>
> *Ou seja, você até pode dizer "se quer mesmo usar o taco, dá pra fazer assim, mas o ideal mesmo é usar vara e anzol (links para sites de pesca)", sem necessariamente explicar como usar vara e anzol. Esse simples detalhe já deixaria as respostas muito melhores, mas nem isso as pessoas querem fazer mais, elas só dizem para usar o taco sem mencionar que é gambiarra (e novamente, se a sua desculpa é "ah, mas e se a pessoa não tiver vara e anzol?", ela só seria válida se essa restrição estivesse na pergunta).*

---

Quando criei minha conta, a minha ideia era contribuir com aquilo que eu achava ser o grande diferencial do site: a qualidade. Não que eu seja especialista em alguma coisa, mas sempre procurei responder da melhor forma possível, tendo em mente as premissas de gerar o repositório de conhecimento, de ir um pouco além do que foi perguntado, de não aceitar qualquer gambiarra, enfim, de ensinar a pescar adequadamente (nem sempre consigo, claro, mas o importante é ter esse *mindset* ao responder).

Mas não só a maioria dos usuários não se preocupa mais com a qualidade, como a própria empresa responsável pelo site têm tido atitudes questionáveis nos últimos anos, dando a entender claramente - só não vê quem não quer - que a quantidade é mais importante que a qualidade (embora o discurso oficial ainda seja de que "qualidade é importante", está cada vez mais claro que na prática não é). Em vez de fazer [coisas assim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803), que ajudariam a manter a qualidade (ou ao menos segurar um pouco a queda) sem sobrecarregar os usuários que ainda se importam, ela prefere fazer [mudanças inúteis que ninguém pediu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/401803) (e [reclamações para revertê-las](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/401803) são sumariamente ignoradas).

Sendo assim, me encontro dividido.

Por um lado, eu quero ajudar a manter a qualidade do site que - apesar da situação atual - foi uma das melhores coisas que aconteceram nos últimos anos para os programadores (**e lembre-se que o site só se tornou o que é por causa da qualidade, e se ela cair, todos - inclusive quem não se importa - saem perdendo**). Por outro lado, questiono se vale a pena dedicar tanto tempo, e de graça, para uma empresa que claramente não se importa mais com a comunidade. Talvez o melhor a fazer é deixá-la colher o que plantou: se todas as ações dos últimos anos privilegiam a quantidade e negligenciam a qualidade, deixemos que ela se transforme no "Yahoo Respostas da programação".

Por um lado, "sabemos" que na internet sempre existe a possibilidade de surgir algo melhor. Por outro lado, quanto tempo teremos que esperar para que isso aconteça? Até lá, teremos que conviver com o que temos.

Por um lado, eu quero muito pedir que você não desista, já que você é um dos que mais se dedicam (atualmente eu diria que é o mais dedicado) ao site. Por outro lado, eu não me vejo no direito de dizer como você deve gastar seu tempo e esforço. Eu mesmo não me dedico 100% ao site (*inclusive nas próximas semanas terei que diminuir bastante minha participação por motivos pessoais*), então eu não posso exigir que outros façam o mesmo.

Resumindo, creio que a decisão seja única e exclusivamente sua. Claro que isso terá consequências, teremos muito mais perguntas ruins com respostas idem, será cada vez mais difícil separar o joio do trigo e encontrar algo realmente bom e útil. Virará um grande *help desk* (e eu mesmo não sei se continuarei participando se o site degringolar de vez). Mas se a SE quer isso (ou pelo menos não agiu para evitar que se transforme nisso), talvez não reste outra alternativa a não ser deixar que [quebrem todas as janelas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/44/112052), pois não há mais gente suficiente para consertá-las.

É a velha história (mais um clichê):

> Tempos difíceis criam pessoas fortes.
>   Pessoas fortes criam tempos fáceis.
>   Tempos fáceis criam pessoas fracas.
>   Pessoas fracas criam tempos difíceis.

Nos tempos difíceis era complicado encontrar informação de qualidade. Estava tudo espalhado por aí, e muitas vezes atrás de *paywalls*.

Aí criaram o Stack Overflow, e ficou tão fácil que as pessoas nem se dão ao trabalho de pesquisar mais (quantas vezes você coloca o exato título da pergunta no Google e vem um monte de resultados com a resposta).

Agora essa legião de preguiçosos está desvirtuando o site, e provavelmente é questão de tempo até ele virar um misto de Yahoo Respostas com *help desk* - estamos perto, não?

Mas - assim espero - um dia surgirá outro site. Ele "resolverá" os problemas atuais, e claro que depois de alguns anos criará outros. E assim seguiremos...

Comment: Claro, a decisão é minha, acho que tenho obrigação de me justificar e se as pessoas acharem que estou fazendo algo errado, estou traindo o site de alguma forma já que fui eleito moderador, apesar das ressalvas que faço sobre isso, eu precisaria mudar um pouco o que fazer. Ainda estou lendo e poderei comentar outras coisas. Quando fala do SO ter respostas tão boas, fala mais do SOen, do SOpt, ou no geral? (a parte dos criadores foi explicitada). Tome o +1 porque não tem como o resto decepcionar.

Comment: @Maniero As respostas boas estão em ambos, mas claro que no SOen tem muito mais. Mas de forma geral, e apesar de tudo, o SOpt tem - principalmente em conteúdo antigo - muita coisa boa também

Comment: Em conteúdo bom parece que vale a pena investir, em conteúdo ruim parece que não ,certo? Quando você só tem *helpdesk* não dá vontade de melhorar aquilo porque não está criando um repositório. Concordam? E obrigado por mais uma vez tentar fazer as pessoas se conscientizarem dos problemas de alguns comportamentos e como isso é maléfico para todos mesmo que as pessoas não se apercebam comprovando o meu link preferido: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect. Daqui umas semanas o meu post será para a SE. Você citou alguns problemas da equipe de UX que eu falo.

Comment: Eu também fico muito dividido, e até me passa pela cabeça desistir de vez, mas não é o que farei agora, até porque tenho outros interesses para continuar. A divisão ocorre muito porque continuar sem fazer o meu melhor não é bom, não me agrada, mas ao mesmo tempo não tenho mais condições de fazer tanto, é o que o bfavaretto falou, está se tornando insustentável. Em condições normais eu continuaria fazendo tudo ou desistiria, mas estou tentando ser flexível por várias razões, algumas pessoais, não vou negar. Não vou esculachar, mas preciso fazer algo mais produtivo.

Comment: Também acho que o SO ainda é melhor do que tudo que tem por aí. Não dá pra negritar um pouco um pouco mais o **inclusive quem não se importa sai perdendo**? :) O meu medo é que se deixar decair eu vou desistir do site porque fica completamente sem condições. Estou tentando evitar isso, porque pra ser sincero, é a decisão mais correta. Não estou querendo assimilar o golpe e partir pra próxima.

Comment: Eu tenho uma certa desesperança sobre aparecer algo melhor. Eu já pensei bem nisso. E até pode, mas mesmo quem gosta de qualidade tem seu limite. E algo que não seja popular tem dificuldade de andar. Eu já falei algumas vezes de um modelo que fosse um pouco mais próximo de uma Wiki, mas não tão engessado. Só populariza se for esculhambado. pensa bem, a Wikipedia um pouco diferente, um pouca mais especializada resolve quase tudo o que temos no SO.(em cada língua) a não ser pelas perguntas *helpdesk*.

Comment: Estou torcendo para realmente surgir algo real ou a SE perceba que está na hora de criar isso, ainda que ninguém confia na empresa mais. E pra falar a verdade não confio em startup alguma mais.

Comment: @Maniero Acho que a ideia de ter um repositório com informações de qualidade escritas por especialistas é meio incompatível com a ideia de ter uma comunidade de milhões de participantes que perguntam e respondem. A maioria, por definição, não é especialista (mesmo quem é, só é em um ou poucos assuntos, então na maior parte do tempo, para a maioria dos assuntos, não somos especialistas). Então ou tem-se um wiki/blog com forte curadoria, ou tem-se o que o SO está se tornando. Não dá pra ter os 2 no mesmo lugar - a menos que algum site muito "disruptivo" (odeio essa palavra) apareça...

Comment: Concordo, eu acho que só funciona o wiki/blog c/ forte curadoria, ainda que incitado por dúvidas de pessoas. Eu acho possível realizar isso, mas não é fácil. Não tenho dúvidas que o Jeff e o Joel são responsáveis pelo sucesso do SO, não é tanto assim a ferramenta. A capacidade deles atraírem massa crítica inicial de qualidade foi o segredo do sucesso. Outras coisas foram secundárias. Acho que dá para ter algo popular no *readonly*, mas também não é fácil estabelecer como será o *grant write*. Quem fizer tem que ter isso claro.

Comment: A StackExchange é ciente deste conflito que estamos passando? Se for, qual é o posicionamento deles?

Comment: @CypherPotato se não, estarão em alguns dias :)

Comment: Eu entrei no SO pelas mesmas razões, eu queria aprender uma linguagem de programação nova. Então todos os dias abria algumas respostas bem escritas e sempre aprendia algo a mais. Quando não entendia muito o que estavam falando, ia pesquisar sobre isso. Hoje tenho dúvidas se devo confiar naquela resposta quando abro algumas perguntas aleatórias. Mas isso se aplica no SOen e, mais grave e frequente, no Sopt.

Comment: E estou com esta resposta sobre o que eu gostaria de falar para o Maniero, estava pensando nas palavras que iria usar. Mas era isso mesmo que está nesta resposta. Não desista do site, mas também não iremos te julgar por desistir. Pois a maioria já não é mais tão ativo e todos sabem que poderiam melhorar, mas estão cansados. Obs.: Se a SE Inc responder um posicionamento, poderia nos informar? Ou um link para o post na SE

Answer (score 6):

O problema de dar uma opinião em um decisão sua é justamente o conflito de interesses.
Por um lado você tem fazer o que é melhor para você, o cidadão Antonio Maniero tem que se preservar e buscar o que é o melhor para si. Por outro lado o site perde e perde muito com a refreada de suas atividades.

Quero você seja feliz e continue dando palestras, respondendo perguntas aqui e no Quora. Achei duas palestras suas no Youtube uma do Araras Dev e outra do Rio Claro Developers, muito boas uma sobre a má prática de seguir as boas prática e outra sobre ERPs.

Mas por outro lado tanto você Maniero como o Bacco, estão quase sozinhos na manutenção da qualidade do conteúdo da página. A comunidade perdeu a capacidade de se auto-gerir, são poucos os membros dispostos a deixar o nome junto ao motivo de fechamento das perguntas. A maioria quer fazer média para ganhar uns pontinhos, uma edição tosca aqui, um comentário ambíguo ali e uma resposta feita para agradar acolá, mas realmente dizer 'NÃO' e bater de frente com o ego de quem precisa de ajuda mas não está psicoemocionalmente pronto para receber, esses são poucos.

Eu como membro comunitário não posso nada a não ser contar com vocês moderadores. Então lendo que você cansou eu me sinto desamparado, eu acredito na página eu acredito que podemos melhorar, mas se quem estava batendo de frente e buscando qualidade joga a toalha... vou fazer o quê... vou esperar a horda de hunos invadir, saquear e pilhar o SOpt?

Não vou ficar de braços cruzados. Estou com você no que decidir, mas volto a insistir nisso aqui: [Devemos diminuir a quantidade de votos necessários para fechar e reabrir perguntas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8132/137387), não vou fazer desta questão uma plataforma para aquela mas já que não vamos mais ter uma moderação atuante quanto aos fechamentos por favor nos deem mais força em nossos votos comunitários.

No demais tenha certeza que você fez muito pela comunidade e muito mais pelos seu integrantes. Nós da nova geração de usuários do site só temos que o agradecer e tocar adiante legado que você e os membros fundadores do Stack Overflow em Português nos deixam.

Maneiro eu só tenho que lhe agradecer pelo privilégio de diariamente estar discutindo e participando dos rumos da comunidade junto de você e toda a equipe de moderação assim como os membros ativos da comunidade.

Tenha certeza de fez o melhor. Meu muito obrigado.

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente o conflito, isso já era o esperado por mim e acho que todos com algum nível de sensatez. Você achou aquelas coisas malucas? :D Que gambi... De ERP não lembro, pode ser que o alemão esteja me perseguindo. Que bom que enxerga que muitos não fecham porque não querem vincular seu nome ali. Eu entendo isso, não estou criticando a atitude, o experimento social de auto gestão não funcionou tão bem assim. E somos uma cidade pequena, quando precisa de participação complica. Todo mundo se conhece, as pessoas engajam quando é certo que não vai dar problema para ela. Parte do ...

Comment: ...problema é um pouco a falta de "anonimato" que tem mais no SOen. Não que seja um anonimato mesmo, mas tudo fica meio perdido, você não cruza com as mesmas pessoas sempre. As pessoas vão querendo se proteger. Eu tenho um pouco essa preocupação do desamparo, mas não tenho muito mais o que fazer. Eu não estou achando mais que reduzir os votos necessários para fechar será a solução, de tão ruim que a situação ficou. E pior ainda se reduzir junto os votos para reabrir porque fica mais fácil alguém que não tem compromisso com a qualidade conseguir reabrir. Mas acho que é algo que pode-se tentar..

Comment: mas tem grande chance de dar errado e piorar, não sei se deve, é conflituoso. Obrigado pelo apoio. Eu reforço que não estou saindo so site, deixando de moderar, e que sei que terão outras pessoas como você que ainda farão sua parte (pelo menos espero), mas também vou compreender se alguém se sentir cansado, desmotivado, todos sempre terão meu apoio porque eu sinto isso também. è complicado quando você tem que lidar com muito mais problemas que ganhos (ainda que muito abstratos).

Answer (score 6):

Vou escrever uma resposta, que na verdade não é uma resposta, mas como comentários ficar impossível :)

Já discuti com o Maniero a respeito de respostas algumas vezes, mas tudo no bom nível da discordância de opiniões e educação, mas no que se refere à qualidade das respostas, já comentei em outra pergunta aqui no meta (desculpem me, não consigo montar essas respostas com os links organizados :)), e sobre a moderação **concordo completamente com a postura em relação à qualidade das perguntas**. Acho que a moderação tem feito um trabalho exemplar, mas é como enxugar gelo, se fecha uma pergunta, aparecem outras 20...

Olha, vejo bem o empenho, às vezes estou estudando no fim de semana e entro pra ver algo no SO, ou aqui no SOPt e tem aquele vício de "dar uma olhadinha" no site, e vejo várias perguntas fechandas aos fins de semana, todo horário, algo a se enaltecer!

Mas indo para o foco da pergunta, só o Maniero pode decidir, mas eu gostaria de dar uma opinião sobre a moderação, em especial, de perguntas: é difícil para o moderador, já que a comunidade para fechar uma pergunta precisa de 5 votos.
Ou precisa de um voto de moderador ou o voto de um usuário com com a medalha ouro na tag. Isso dificulta demais... talvez se baixasse para 3 votos do mesmo tipo (3 duplicados, 3 precisa de esclarecimentos, etc), ou ainda que um usuário com medalha prata (que já são poucos) pudessem fechar perguntas, seria menos trabalho pra todos, e muito menos para os moderadores.

Isso iria ao menos diminuir a carga.

Agora vamos a outro ponto: concordância sobre o que fechar. Aqui é um ponto a se pensar. Sempre vai haver uma discordância, mas no geral, vejo que os votos de fechar da comunidade estão alinhados, mas talves precisamos discutir bem no meta, e convidar a comunidade a ler (um banner no top, banner mesmo, tipo `<marquee`> :) ) e se alinhar quanto a isso.

Já vi boas perguntas aqui em inglês. Deixei comentário explicando e pedindo para traduzir para PT, faço isso sempre e é uma pena fechar, mas votei pra fechar porque esse é o entendimento da comunidade. Se criar esse conceito e a maioria estiver alinhada, talvez seja mais fácil isso funcionar. Sei lá, posso estar sendo otimista demais, mas não se sabe se não tentar não é?

É isso, no mais, continuem fazendo o bom trabalho de sempre, como dizem "menos é mais", é melhor ter menos perguntas, mas com qualidade, do que só quantidade, é o que penso.

Comment: pf, comentem sobre as sugestões da medalha e diminuir o número de votos pra fechar

Comment: Sobre os votos para fechar, acho que faz mais sentido continuar a discussão [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8132/112052) (se bem que parece que não vai sair mais nada de lá, mas sei lá, vai que de repente alguém "ressucita" a discussão e a SE resolve fazer alguma coisa). Já a questão da medalha, acho que é o caso de [criar outra pergunta](/questions/ask), pois aí a discussão fica mais organizada (as pessoas podem responder com suas ressalvas e sugestões, votar, etc)

Comment: Ricardo, eu sou favorável ao a diminuição do limiar de votos para fechamento de perguntas, concordo integralmente que isso diminuiria a carga imposta a moderação. Outra coisa que estou amadurecendo é a possibilidade de aproveitar os usuários mais tempo ou mais pontos(isso me excluiria) como moderadores temporários em dias ou horários críticos, mas a sugestão formal disso depende de muita leitura aqui no meta pois vejo a cultura do site sendo algo rico e complexo então não adianta ainda criar um tópico sem embasamento nos princípios da comunidade.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, seria um moderador com permissões limitadas a tarefas específicas, é isso? parece interessante

Comment: @hkotsubo nossa, essa pergunta é mesmo antiga, mas tem opiniões muito interessantes lá, podemos tentar adicionar responstas e comentários e ver se anda

Comment: O recuso já está liberado só falta a comunidade se expressar apresentando a opinião individual de usuário naquela pergunta para ser ativado. É democracia, mas quando as pessoas se calam fica difícil tomar decisões pela coletividade pois depois ficam falando que a decisão é de um grupo,da panela, dos amigos, ..... todos temos que levantar a mão e falar qual o rumo que desejamos.