# 2020: moderação do site em números

Tags: debate, moderação, estatísicas

Gostaria de compartilhar com vocês um relatório sobre a moderação do Stack Overflow em Português.

Uma característica distinta dos sites da rede Stack Exchange é a forma como estes são moderados:

> A rede Stack Exchange foi desenhada para ser auto-regulada, de modo que o custo de moderação do sistema é amortizado em milhares de pequenas porções de esforço diário dos usuários regulares.
> -- [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Embora existam [Moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), uma parte significativa da *moderação* é feita por pessoas comuns, usando os privilégios obtidos através das suas contribuições ao site. Cada um de vocês contribui com um pouco do seu tempo e esforço, e juntos todos conseguem realizar muita coisa.

Ao entrar em um novo ano, vamos fazer uma pausa e refletir, e por um momento apreciar o trabalho que todos fizemos juntos. Para isso, vejamos como foi feita a moderação no Stack Overflow em Português, dividido por atividade, nos últimos 12 meses:

| Ação | Moderadores | Comunidade¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Usuários suspensos² | 192 | 25 |
| Usuários destruídos | 82 | 0 |
| Usuários deletados | 139 | 0 |
| Usuários contatados | 510 | 0 |
| Suspensões reconsideradas antes do término | 2 | 0 |
| Usuários banidos da revisão | 17 | 0 |
| Revisões³: Edições sugeridas | 267 | 8559 |
| Revisões³: Votos para reabrir | 1795 | 5722 |
| Revisões³: Publicações de baixa qualidade | 16 | 11915 |
| Revisões³: Respostas tardias | 8 | 2980 |
| Revisões³: Primeiras publicações | 58 | 16949 |
| Revisões³: Votos para fechar | 400 | 8216 |
| Tags mescladas | 10 | 0 |
| Propostas de sinônimos de tag | 10 | 3 |
| Sinônimos de tag criados | 10 | 0 |
| Definição de coloração de sintaxe de tags | 9 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 27 | 0 |
| Perguntas desprotegidas | 2 | 1 |
| Perguntas reabertas | 277 | 47 |
| Perguntas protegidas | 19 | 103 |
| Perguntas migradas | 2 | 0 |
| Perguntas mescladas | 3 | 0 |
| Perguntas sinalizadas⁴ | 849 | 7277 |
| Perguntas fechadas | 17490 | 1546 |
| Sinalizações de perguntas tratadas⁴ | 4432 | 3675 |
| Publicações desbloqueadas | 15 | 63 |
| Publicações restauradas | 172 | 795 |
| Publicações bloqueadas | 92 | 345 |
| Publicações apagadas⁵ | 3015 | 29764 |
| Publicações levantadas à página principal | 0 | 8545 |
| Escalações ao time de CMs | 16 | 0 |
| Comentários restaurados | 90 | 0 |
| Comentários sinalizados | 245 | 544 |
| Comentários apagados⁶ | 2457 | 5616 |
| Sinalizações de comentários tratadas | 715 | 74 |
| Respostas sinalizadas | 1546 | 6903 |
| Sinalizações de respostas tratadas | 7138 | 1303 |
| Comentários de um post movidos para o chat | 46 | 0 |

#### Observações

¹ "Comunidade" se refere tanto a [membros do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users) *sem* [o diamante próximo ao seus nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), e ao sistema automático conhecido como [user #-1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² O sistema suspende um usuário em três circunstâncias: quando o usuário é recriado depois de ser suspenso anteriormente, quando é recriado depois de ser destruído por *spam* ou abuso, ou quando a conta sofre uma suspensão em toda a rede.

³ Inclui todas as revisões que não foram puladas - ou seja, as duas revisões necessárias para as Edições Sugeridas contam como 2, pois o objetivo é indicar a frequência das ações de moderação. O mesmo se aplica a sinalizações, etc.

⁴ Inclui sinalizações de fechamento (mas *não* os votos para fechar ou reabrir).

⁵ Ignora os inúmeros casos em que a publicação é apagada automaticamente em resposta a alguma ação.

⁶ Inclui comentários apagados pelos próprios autores (que também considera algumas sinalizações de comentários que foram tratadas).

(Muito obrigado a [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) por todo o trabalho com as queries SQL.)

Comment: Qual é a posição da SE em relação a esses números? Estão satisfeitos?

Comment: @Woss É uma boa pergunta, obrigado! O que mais me preocupa é o número de perguntas fechadas dos moderadores. Quais são seus pensamentos?

Comment: Chegou a analisar a qualidade das publicações fechadas? Ou somente achou que é um **número** muito alto? Se são 17k publicações **ruins** fechadas, esse número não deveria preocupar - na verdade, até deveria mais ainda, porque aí é a plataforma que está permitindo criarem esse tipo de conteúdo ruim.

Comment: Se há muitas perguntas fechadas, é porque a qualidade geral caiu muito, e se a maioria dos fechamentos é feita por moderadores, é porque a comunidade não tem ajudado (há poucos usuários com mais de 3000 pontos, e desses só uma minoria usa os votos de fechamento - tem uns que **nunca** deram um único voto sequer) então o número é só consequência de outros problemas. Na minha opinião, uma das causas principais é o site permitir que tantas perguntas ruins sejam feitas (a nova página de fazer pergunta não deveria ajudar nisso? [Pelo jeito não](/q/8246/112052))

Comment: Sem contar que isso é um grande *déjà vu* do ano passado, quando tivemos essa mesma discussão. Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8311/112052

Comment: Acho que não é só comigo, mas se analisarem o meu perfil por exemplo, há perguntas em que voto para o fechamento pedindo esclarecimento, passam-se dias onde essas perguntas continuam abertas, não sendo esclarecidas ou modificadas, e então tenho que sinalizar a moderação apresentando motivos e pedindo o fechamento.

Comment: Estou na mesma que o Augusto. Penso bastante antes de votar para  fechar, e mais ainda antes de sinalizar. Mesmo assim já acumulei mais de 80 sinalizações, quase todos sobre perguntas de baixa qualidade ou respostas que não são respostas. Não sei o que seria dos site sem os moderados fechando essas perguntas.
Mudando completamente de assunto: 8826 Revisões de Edições sugeridas e eu nunca consigo encontrar uma na Fila de Análise (Faltam 7 para minha medalha de revisor). Ou meus horários são muito exóticos ou está todo mundo buscando a mesma medalha :D.