# Qual a postura da SE sobre a moderação comunitária?

Tags: debate, comunidade, moderação

Dando continuidade ao que comecei em [Como moderar o SOpt?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8349/101). Importante ler para pegar todo o contexto.

Quero reforçar a ideia que estou falando aqui que o problema é a moderação comunitária, e falo principalmente do que eu faço nessa parte de moderação. Não estou falando da moderação diamante que é relativamente fácil e não traz tantos problemas (retaliações).

Estou querendo uma posição da SE, embora todos possam comentar sobre, talvez até para enriquecer o debate. Queria toda clareza possível, mesmo o histórico indicar que não acontecerá.

Eu sei que eu faço só o que eu quiser, mas sempre fiz tudo o que estava ao meu alcance para manter o site em alto nível.

E quero deixar claro que espero uma resposta para eu tomar uma decisão, por isso, apesar de expor os problemas do site, a postagem é mais do meu interesse, até porque os problemas não serão solucionados. Eu preciso postar isso para manter minha consciência de que fiz o que pude.

## Moderação comunitária

A comunidade, de forma geral, já desistiu do site. Poucas pessoas ajudam e mesmo assim em volume pequeno. Infelizmente tenho que dizer que quem mais faz moderação, de forma bastante isolada, sou eu, até porque semana a semana isso piora. Claro que tem outras pessoas que fazem aqui e ali, em momentos que podem, e sou grato a todos, mas não posso fazer de conta que o que faz a diferença maior é minha atuação, e que se eu diminuir haverá um efeito dominó de outras pessoas desistirem, até porque as janelas estarão tão quebradas que o padrão será o ruim. Ninguém quer esse ambiente. Sei de algumas que já estão em vias de fazer isso.

Infelizmente hoje grande parte das respostas são ruins. E “ensinam” errado, no passado isso era mais raro. Esses conteúdos ruins eram corretamente classificados e muitas vezes até desapareciam do site. Hoje isso não acontece tanto. Mesmo as respostas só são ruins porque as perguntas costumam ser ruins. As perguntas são o real problema.

Os usuários novos acham que aqui é grupo de WhatsApp ou rede social, antes já achávamos ruim acharem que era fórum. Elas não entendem o que é um site de Q&A. Alguns experientes no site não entendem. Pode pôr *banner* para ajudar e vai mudar nada. Os usuários não querem ver nada, não querem ser instruídos. Nada que tentamos funcionou. Eles não querem criar um repositório de conhecimento, só querem que as pessoas ajudem ou façam o trabalho deles. E quando falo de ajuda, estou dizendo que eles querem algo interativo individual, o que chamamos de *help desk*, que não cria conhecimento que pode ser usado por outras pessoas. Ainda mais do jeito que postam, não ajudam sequer no SEO.

Algumas pessoas cansaram de fazer todo esse trabalho inócuo. Eu entendo perfeitamente. Algumas pessoas não querem fazer isso porque sofrem retaliações. E as ferramentas não ajudam.

As pessoas enxergam que a SE não está melhorando o site para diminuir o trabalho de moderação e melhorar a qualidade. Dá até a impressão que a SE dificulta para as pessoas não moderarem mesmo e aí aumentar a quantidade em detrimento da qualidade.

Mesmo que esta percepção estivesse errada, e não parece estar, ainda assim é o que acontece.

Usuários que postavam com qualidade desistiram ou estão desistindo. Algumas até acham que a moderação deveria ser menor, mas elas ajudam em nada. Elas reclamam e vão embora, não fazem a parte deles.

Usuários de pouco uso sempre acham que o site será melhor se tudo for liberado, que a moderação seja baixa. Em geral eles ficam pouco tempo, não colaboram para a qualidade aumentar, só querem que tudo seja uma bagunça. Eles querem só a quantidade. É do interesse de muitos que qualquer porcaria continue no site para elas responderem qualquer coisa, é onde elas podem "brilhar". Algumas pessoas ativamente não querem que o conteúdo seja classificado como negativo, mesmo ele sendo. Elas não ligam para as consequências desastrosas, elas têm compromisso com o erro.

Obviamente que os usuários menos ativos só fazem perguntas e querem **receber ajuda**. Não ligam para nada. Não sei como dizer de forma mais leve, mas vemos um misto de preguiça, em alguns casos desonestidade, e até analfabetismo funcional. Não tem como lidar com essas pessoas, por uma razão ou por outra. Algumas até fazem um esforço para tudo sair certo, mas não possuem condições de fazer isso. Alguns querem qualquer resposta que faça funcionar, até que os prejudique. E alguns usuários fornecem esse tipo de resposta.

Não é só isso, eles também não votam, não aceitam respostas, não leem outras postagens (antes todas postagens antigas bem populares tinham votos quase todos os dias, agora chega ficar meses sem um voto novo), eles não retribuem, não seguem instruções, não tentam ver se já foi perguntado antes algo idêntico, eles esperneiam, acham que tudo gira em torno deles. Claro, nem todos fazem tudo isso, mas fazem uma parte.

E o peso de lidar com isso recai nas costas dos usuários mais ativos. E é muito trabalho, e nada gratificante, porque quase sempre não sai um resultado positivo, e em boa parcela acontece um *stress*.

Mesmo que as pessoas já não estejam mais atuando com toda paciência, dá para entender depois de tanto trabalho e dor de cabeça que tem acontecido para elas.

## Queda de qualidade

Não sei em outros sites da rede, mas aqui é desproporcional o trabalho que dá.

Ignore os números reais, aa proporção exata, só para dar um parâmetro vamos dizer que no começo de 25 perguntas. 5 eram ruins e tinha 20 usuários com condições de lidar com elas, então de vez em quando você lidava com uma.

Agora dessas 25, 20 são ruins, e tem uma pessoa para lidar com essas 20. Sim, mesmo não sendo números medidos, a proporção da carga de trabalho de moderação comunitária não é tão diferente de ter piorado 100 vezes.

É impraticável continuar assim. E eu e outras pessoas desistindo de ser quem lida com isso, imagina o que vai acontecer?

Pode dizer o que quiser, mas vamos virar o Yahoo! Respostas de vez, o que já está em andamento.

Mesmo as pessoas que ainda fazem alguma coisa para ajudar, muitas vezes são atividades inefetivas. Boa parte das edições não melhoram nada que salve uma pergunta. Muitas vezes é só para ganhar pontos. Mesmo as pessoas de mais boa vontade já não ligam tanto. Teve época que eu editava quase tudo, agora edito quase só o que respondo, consequência: quase tudo no site fica como garranchos. Cansei!

## Retaliação

Alia-se ao fato da SE não ajudar muito em outra área complicada que é a da retaliação. Eu poderia falar da retaliação branca velada, onde a pessoa não positiva mais alguém que ela não gosta, e isso acaba sendo viral, meio que todo mundo começa fazer isso e vira uma guerra. Eu entendo que é difícil resolver isso, mas algo deveria ser feito. Querendo, tem solução. Mas o problema passa até por retaliações mais claras com negativos. Muitas vezes a SE não quer se dar ao trabalho de analisar casos onde isso ocorre porque não tem um padrão absurdo e fácil. Mas são casos que quando vai analisando com mais profundidade as indicações estão ali. Uma vez o *dashboard* teve um *bug* e mostrou coisas que moderadores não costumam poder ver e com pouca informação extra ficou muito óbvio que alguns casos havia perseguição e que a SE não vê quando não quer. Tem que montar o histórico todo do ocorrido, não é só olhar os números.

Até o sistema não ajuda. Esses dias tive 5 *downs* seguidos de um usuário, e aconteceu depois que fechei uma postagem problemática dele, e o sistema não reverteu, o que praticamente impossibilita os moderadores fazerem algo.

E quando a retaliação ocorre em um moderador fica complicado lidar, em geral é melhor escalar para a SE. Mas é comum passar meses sem resposta alguma. Há casos de anos. Sequer negam, só fica sem resposta.

Tem usuário que prega que ninguém deveria dar negativo, mas ele dá um ou outro negativo... só em mim. Se isso não é retaliação não sei mais o que é. Eu poderia falar de vários casos que a pessoa indica ser retaliação quando ela mostra isso em comentários.

Há pessoas que você não pode mais negativar, por mais que seja o correto, porque a pessoa descobriu como saber quem negativou, pelo menos se for um usuário que está na mira dele, e aí ele retalia. Advinha se são usuários que produzem qualidade?

## Frustrante

Acham motivante ficar dando o sangue pelo site, fazer o “trabalho sujo”, receber retaliações e não receber proteção por isso?

Não há mais usuários em número suficiente dando positivos ou para dividir a carga de trabalho. Cada vez tem mais pessoas fazendo retaliações, alguns de forma que realmente dificulta garantir que é retaliação porque fazem de forma sofisticada. E a SE acha normal. Desmotiva.

Não ganhamos para fazer esse trabalho todo e ter mais desgostos do que gostos. Não é fácil ver esse trabalho sendo desvalorizado ou desmerecido.

Eu até admito que por vezes faço uma moderação comunitária correndo. Já gasto cerca de uma hora do meu dia fazendo isso, e é muito. Se eu fizer tudo o que alguns demandam vai quase o dia todo, só poderia fazer isso se fosse meu trabalho.

Como continuar quando tudo vai contra? Quando esse trabalho não é valorizado, quase se recebe desprezo, ataque.

A turma do "quanto pior melhor" deve estar feliz lendo isso, mas o prejudicado é o site, é toda a comunidade, os usuários que podemos ajudar de verdade.

## A SE não colabora

Eu sei que a SE continuará discursando que quer qualidade, mas suas ações não ajudam isso e dizem o contrário. Tenho quase certeza que a resposta aqui (ou ausência dela) confirmará tudo o que eu digo.

A SE faz coisas que ninguém pediu, muitas vezes piorando. O que poderia melhor, e nem acho que seja fácil, mas deveriam estar fazendo há tempos, ela não faz. Já pedimos várias vezes muitas melhorias. A maioria a gente sabe que não vai acontecer.

Não quero culpar os funcionários, acredito que a filosofia de crescer à qualquer custo é o problema, e mesmo que algum funcionário fosse o problema ainda seria um problema da empresa.

Não temos mais o mesmo site que existia quando começamos. Não temos o que nos propuseram quando abraçamos a causa. Não é mais um Q&A com compromisso com a qualidade.

A percepção dos usuários mais ativos é que a SE gosta dos usuários novatos que não colaboram, e odeiam os usuários experientes que podem produzir conteúdo de qualidade. Fica difícil.

## Melhorias que precisamos desesperadamente

Tudo isso nos leva a ser uma espécie de Y!R. Eu sei que temos ferramentas melhores para isso não acontecer, mas as pessoas cansaram de usar quando elas não são efetivas, quando dá muito trabalho.

- O SOpt chegou em estado tão lamentável, e não pensem que é exagero, que o melhor a fazer é começar a postagem fechada e a comunidade abre o que ficar claro que dá para dar uma boa resposta. Isso sozinho ajudaria muito, ainda que outras coisas ainda seriam necessárias. Vai acontecer? Sei que não, mas deveria. Seria uma demonstração que a qualidade está em primeiro lugar.

  Concentrando no que vale a pena pode ficar mais gratificante. Diminuiria o desgaste.
- Anonimizar (de verdade) certas coisas que acabam sendo negativas seria outra medida importante.
- Criar barreiras para as pessoas perguntarem, como por exemplo o Wizard que instrui e obriga a pessoa pensar sobre, seria fundamental.

  Quem tem tempo de casa deve saber que a SE desistiu do Wizard porque as pessoas se frustravam com isso. Mas elas estão se frustrando mais ainda com fechamentos e negativos, e sem comentários. Afinal todo mundo cansou, não adianta comentar na maioria das vezes. É muita tentativa para uma dar certo.
- Grande parte da documentação e mensagens do sistema precisam ser revisadas pela comunidade para deixar mais claro o que é aquilo. Hoje os textos são ambíguos e simplificados demais.
- Permitir que usuários estabelecidos tenham votos adicionais conforme o nível de participação. Tem dia que é preciso dar mais de 40 negativos.

Não vou citar uma lista completa porque isso já tem aqui e no metão, mas parece que vai contra os interesses da SE. Algumas ideias foram passadas em [Se você pudesse alterar QUALQUER coisa no site, o que mudaria?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/101). Mas tem em vários outros lugares.

As ferramentas precisam ser ideais, próximas da perfeição, elas precisam dar pouco trabalho para as pessoas, precisam fazer quase tudo mais automático e deixar as pessoas só tomarem a decisão final. Elas precisam entregar o trabalho mais pesado para as pessoas só fazerem o nobre. A SE tem adotado uma postura de fazer as pessoas trabalharem mais.

## Site se tornando inviável

E o conteúdo ruim vai denegrindo todo o site. Afasta anunciantes de bom nível se um dia for o caso. Faz a percepção de todos que o SOpt não é uma fonte confiável. Que aqui está cheio de perguntas e respostas que, por exemplo incentivam SQL Injection. Não tem como combater isso, é enxugar gelo.

O SOpt, e quem sabe outros sites da rede, estão se tornando repositório de como fazer errado. A [cauda longa](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) se tonou inadministrável.

## Conclusão

Eu não estou abandonando o site, mas não sei se não chegará o dia, por tanto problema que me traz. E nesse dia talvez eu terei vontade de apagar rastros de que eu estive aqui porque haverá uma quantidade de conteúdo ruim tão grande que o bom fica enterrado e perde credibilidade. Sei que não posso fazer isso, mas é mais frustrante ver que entrei em um site e hoje estou em outro em nada tem a ver com o que eu esperava ser.

Não tem como dar o mesmo valor para todos usuários. Há conflito entre estes dois tipos. **Quem é mais importante para a SE, quem pergunta de qualquer jeito e não se compromete com o site ou quem responde e modera com qualidade e faz de tudo para o site funcionar como repositório de conteúdo?**

**De verdade, a SE fará alguma coisa concreta para reverter essa situação no SOpt, de forma rápida com alguma eficácia real?**

**Faz diferença pra SE eu abandonar o trabalho, que me traz mais problemas do que benefícios, e o site virar o Yahoo! Respostas de vez, ou tanto faz? Ou ainda, talvez seja o que esperam?**

Comment: Se um dia você resolver deixar o SOpt certamente vai piorar a qualidade do site, mas se sair acredito que não só eu mas todos vamos entender. É muito trabalho para pouco resultado em termos de qualidade etc. No inicio eu já escrevi muita pergunta ruim e com o passar do tempo aqui no SOpt aprendi muitas coisas sobre perguntas e respostas e acredito ter melhorado, mas não é todo mundo que procura ler e entender como funciona o site. Ainda assim, obrigado pela sua paciência e tempo para tentar manter o site com a melhor qualidade possível.

Comment: @SamuelRenanGonçalvesVaz é um alento ver pessoas evoluindo no SOpt. Ninguém nasceu sabendo, o que estraga o SOpt são as pessoas que querem morrer sem saber. Eu acho que evolui muito aqui. Agora isso não acontece mais, e, em certo ponto de vista, estou piorando, por isso preciso tomar um rumo.

Comment: Eu concordo com a visão que tem em geral, tanto que eu enquadro-me num dos que já muito pouco frequenta o site. A ideia que tenho é que a SE não tá nem ai. Para eles se isto virar Yahoo respostas então está tudo bem na mesma, desde que o tráfego e quantidade de acessos pelo google e outras fontes se mantenha. No final eles querem números apenas, tudo o resto é secundário, tanto que isso já deu polémica em várias decisões que tomaram no passado como o aumento da pontuação nas perguntas. Resumindo, a comunidade vai sentir bastante a sua falta se você sair, mas a SE nem por isso.

Comment: Uma edição recente feita pelo staff removeu a tag [status-revisão] e não deixou nenhuma outra de status no lugar. Isso, somado à [resposta que não responde nada](/a/8393/112052), só confirma que a SE não considera esta questão digna de sequer ser olhada, quanto mais discutida. Tudo bem, já sabíamos disso há muito tempo (antes até desta pergunta ser feita), esse é só mais um dos inúmeros indícios que reforçam esta percepção.

Answer (score 11):

Dada a resposta da SE insípida e burocrática, venho dizer que hoje é um dia muito triste que marca o início do fim de uma era, e o objetivo desta postagem é ser essa marca, apesar que o processo se iniciou há muito tempo e ainda vai continuar.

Não vou fazer um texto muito grande porque quase tudo já foi falado.

Há quase 10 anos a saga começou: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese. Não foi fácil fazer a proposta do SOpt chegar até aqui. Desde o princípio tive muita dedicação ao site e acreditava que estava colaborando para *criar uma internet melhor*.

Tivemos muitas discussões, muita gente pensava diferente, não acreditavam que poderia piorar, que não precisava de moderação muito extensiva. Não adianta falar muito disso, o fato é que o SOpt é um lugar ruim para se perguntar e se obter resposta nos dias de hoje. Não tem mais o que fazer sem a clara participação de todos buscando isso e não ter dissidências, e com a SE fazendo a parte deles que é entregar ferramentas adequadas e direção que a qualidade é o que importa.

Claro que o conteúdo mais antigo e alguma coisa nova ainda tem utilidade, mas o grosso do que se cria agora não tem e não dá mais para administrar isso para ser o tal repositório de conhecimento que queríamos.

Eu fiz tudo o que estava ao meu alcance, me prejudiquei de várias maneiras dentro e fora do site, sempre defendo ele fora e tentando melhorar dentro, mas como a SE não conseguiu demonstrar claramente que não vai facilitar nossa vida, evitar as retaliações não tenho como continuar toda dedicação que eu tinha antes.

Não estou me despedindo do site ou mesmo abandonando a moderação. Nem mesmo vou parar de moderar comunitariamente como todos, mas farei bem menos agora.

Nesses quase 7 anos de existência do site fiz muito:

- Mais de 400 mil pontos em mais de 1000 *tags*
- Mais de 6500 respostas
- Mais de 2600 medalhas
- Mais de 10 milhões de "pessoas ajudadas"
- Mais de 40 mil visitas no perfil
- Mais de 2300 dias de atividade
- Mais de 40 mil votos dados
- Mais de 18 mil edições feitas
- Mais de 25 mil comentários postados (fora os apagados)
- Mais de 1600 sinalizações dadas
- Mais de 600 publicações no meta
- Mais de 7200 publicações ao todo
- Mais de 30 mil *posts* fechados
- Mais de 10 mil comentários removidos
- Mais de 300 mensagens de advertência ou suspensão para usuários
- Mais de 12 mil sinalizações processadas
- Muita participação no chat (até ter desistido de tanta regra que tinha que seguir)
- O primeiro autor de respostas ou entre os primeiros na maioria das principais *tags* de tecnologias
- Algumas centenas de *haters* abertos e milhares de admiradores colecionados.

Acho que cumpri meu papel.

Eu quis fazer o *post* para deixar claro que eu fiz o que pude e que agora não me responsabilizo por nada mais que aconteça ao site, conviverei até onde der com a baixa qualidade, talvez eu ainda seja quem mais moderará mesmo fazendo bem menos, e se não for tanto, estarei entre ou que moderam mais.

Foi bom por um período e não me arrependo porque foi útil de várias formas, fiz amigos, colecionei alegrias. Agora vou, aos poucos, mudar toda minha atuação, não quero que se surpreendam. Faço com a certeza que os bons usuários compreendem.

Continuem contando com minha ajuda e tenho até um pedido para fazer: **SINALIZEM!** Agora será mais importante quando o problema exigir moderação de diamante. Eu continuarei vendo tudo tomando as ações devidas. Abusem mesmo, mostre que precisa de alguma intervenção. Dê prioridade para os motivos padrões, e se for necessário explicar, manda uma mensagem na sinalização personalizada quando requerer atenção da moderação eleita.

Aos poucos minha moderação será (mais) insípida e burocrática, já indicaram que deve ser assim. Lamento pelos que acham que deveria ser diferente. Ainda farei mais do que a SE faz pelo site.

Agradeço a todos e conto com vocês ainda. Me desculpem os que desagradei, a intenção não era essa, só fiz o que era necessário.

Comment: Eu penso que se a intenção da SE é popularizar a ferramenta Teams evidenciando quantidade na expectativa de obter qualidade como valor consequente é uma estratégia de negócio equivocada. A SE quer apresentar o Teams como sendo utilizável desde o think tank, desenvolvimento, suporte e formação de base de conhecimento, deveria priorizar a maior vitrine que possui que são sites SO e seus membros ativos e diamante pois esses membros que no dia a dia com suas atividades elevam a qualidade do conteúdo veiculado. PS: SE... dividam o pão, moderadores deveriam ser remunerados.

Comment: Considerando como estão as coisas e que vai começar uma eleição daqui há apenas umas poucas horas, vou fazer a pergunta diretamente: Você vai renunciar? Ou continuará moderando independente de quem concorra ou ganhe a eleição? Em tempo: não penso em me candidatar. O vislumbre e inspiração que eu tinha em 2018 agora tornou-se em desânimo e amargura.

Comment: @VictorStafusa conforme está escrito vou continuar, porque a moderação de diamante dá bem pouco trabalho, e mesmo que eu ficasse sozinho daria conta sem maiores problemas. O que estou dizendo que é que falta moderação comunitária, isso dá uma imenso trabalho e precisa ser dividido entre centenas de pessoas, o que não tem mais no site. Pra mim não importa quem entre na moderação, desde que ela entre para colaborar e não para criar problema. Eu estou mais ou menos na mesma que você, o site não é mais algo bacana e entendo todos que querem ficar mais afastados.

Comment: Chegará meu dia de sair da moderação e provavelmente do site em definitivo, mas não será hoje. Se perceber eu já estava e nos últimos dias minha participação está diminuindo bastante, vou me concentrar mais na moderação diamante e algo coisa que me dê prazer, o que está raro aparecer. E espero que entre alguém na moderação para colaborar, gostaria de alguém que faça rolar um pouco mais de punições, muitas vezes faço nada porque não tenho apoio de outros (nem contrariedade, o que me obriga não fazer algo que eu acho que deveria).

Answer (score -1):

Muito obrigado a [@JNat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat) pela tradução.

---

Obrigado pela sua pergunta. Acho que você levantou uma questão bastante interessante e importante. Antes de entrarmos em detalhes, quero enfatizar que nós ouvimos o teu feedback, bem como o do resto dos usuários e tomamos ações com base no mesmo. Por exemplo, podemos olhar para:

- Quão frequentemente perguntas levam a tag `[status-completed]` no [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed?tab=Active) e em muitos outros Metas. O número é enorme.
- Iniciativas relacionadas com moderação, como o [Moderator Council](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347104/274323) ou o [Moderator Training](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340012/274323)
- Ou [o nosso roteiro público](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344178/274323) e [compromisso para responder aos Metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586/274323).

Estas são apenas algumas coisas, e há muitas mais iniciativas em que a empresa está a trabalhar para melhorar a nossa plataforma pública (de perguntas e respostas).

Ao mesmo tempo, entendo os teus sentimentos sobre *o teu site*. Como qualquer outro dos sites internacionais, o Stack Overflow em Português tem um papel único no ecossistema do Stack Exchange. Por vezes isso é uma piada cruel para a comunidade. Vamos pensar no que nos impede de sermos uma [das comunidades com mais “buzz” na rede](https://stackexchange.com/sites#answers) e de nos tornarmos no melhor site para obter respostas para qualquer pergunta de programação em português.

### Qualidade dos posts

#### <s>(Qualidade vs Quantidade)</s> Qualidade => Quantidade

O nosso mantra é “Qualidade leva a quantidade. Mas não vice versa. Porque quantidade é um resultado da alta qualidade.”

#### Qualidade é a variável de segunda ordem

Qualidade é o resultado de boa moderação, boa moderação é o resultado de boas regras e políticas, boas regras e políticas são o resultado dos nossos *esforços conjuntos no meta* para estabelecer o site para nós mesmos, portanto...

#### O Meta é a chave

Se compararmos o Stack Overflow em Português a um barco, este seria um cruzeiro, nada menos. Em Junho, foi visitado por 0.9 milhões de pessoas. Isto é muito. Independentemente do quão hábil o capitão é, sem um mecânico, timoneiro, navegação e muitas mais pessoas, um barco desta dimensão não sai do porto. É necessária uma tripulação dedicada para operar tal embarcação.

A situação da qualidade é a mesma. [A nossa missão](/help/manifesto) é criar uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para todas as perguntas de programação. Isto é um destino digno que precisa de um barco grande e uma tripulação hábil. O crescimento da comunidade implica o crescimento de regras de colaboração e o envolvimento dos nossos colegas, não só no processo de fazer e responder a perguntas, mas também no de manter a qualidade, i.e. moderação. Assim sendo, uma das maneiras mais eficazes de aumentar a qualidade do conteúdo é:

- Encontrar utilizadores que têm interesse na qualidade do conteúdo.
- Discutir e criar um conjunto de regras e políticas para moderação *em conjunto*.
- Moderar em equipe de acordo com as regras criadas.

#### Uma viagem comprida começa com um pequeno passo

A empresa em geral, e eu em particular, estamos aqui para estar ao seu serviço. Vamos discutir problemas específicos juntos com o máximo de atenção da comunidade, sem culpabilização, e um problema de cada vez. Depois moderemos o site em conformidade enquanto uma equipe.

Ademais, penso que organizar algumas atividades para aumentar a qualidade do site pode ser um bom princípio. Por exemplo, no passado o [Stack Overflow em Russo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1340/6) e mais recentemente o [Stack Overflow em Japonês](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3355/78) realizaram eventos para aumentar a taxa de perguntas respondidas, passando pela base de conhecimento existente e votando a favor de boas respostas sem votos, respondendo a boas perguntas sem respostas, e votando contra e apagando más perguntas. É só um exemplo de muitas possibilidades de eventos colectivos que nos ajudariam a envolver utilizadores em actividades de moderação e a melhorar a qualidade do conteúdo.

O que pensam, colegas?

Comment: Tenho anos de experiencia com diferentes fóruns (5 no minimo) sobre o mesmo tópico, tecnologia e programação, quantidade e qualidade nunca foram sinônimos lá, estou desde 2014 no SOpt e tive a mesma impressão, não são sinônimos e não se complementam. Mas é apenas a minha opinião.

Comment: Se qualidade é realmente mais importante, deveriam mostrar isso com ações, mas todas as decisões recentes da SE dão a entender que ela na verdade prioriza a quantidade. O nosso problema atual (que não foi respondido) é que a quantidade de usuários que ainda se importam e tentam manter a qualidade é muito pequena e não damos conta da enorme quantidade de usuários que não querem aprender como o site funciona e insistem no helpdesk e na baixa qualidade. O que a SE está fazendo para nos ajudar nesse sentido? Só dizer que qualidade é importante não adianta, queremos acões concretas.

Comment: Já coloquei esse link algumas vezes, e volto a insistir: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803 - o sistema deveria instruir melhor os usuários, e a comunidade deveria apenas cuidar das exceções. Mas hoje é o contrário: o site não ajuda a fazer perguntas boas (a página de fazer pergunta, que deveria fazer esse filtro, [não faz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8250/112052)), e a SE prefere fazer [mudanças questionáveis que ninguém pediu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/401803) e [ignora o _feedback_ da comunidade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/401803).

Comment: Troque o mantra pois quantidade e qualidade são grandezas distintas, incomparáveis e não relacionáveis.

Comment: "realizaram eventos para aumentar a taxa de perguntas respondidas" - O problema com uma eventual baixa taxa de perguntas respondidas é porque as perguntas são bem fracas, para não dizer péssimas. Onde quero chegar é que esse indicador não revela nada só por si, e não deve ser um marco de sucesso eu acho. Na minha opinião esse baixo índice de perguntas respondidas só vem confirmar o atual problema com a qualidade das perguntas feitas.