# Quem é remunerado na rede?

Tags: debate

Vendo as [perguntas que vão servir de base para escolha dos novos moderadores](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8400/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2020-coleta-de-perguntas), fiquei com uma duvida cruel em relação a ganhar ou não (*dinheiro*, *salário*, *bonificação*, **etc.**) sendo um usuário de destaque na rede.

Os moderadores *que eu sei bem que é totalmente voluntário* não tem ganho salariais e acima dos moderadores tem os que cuidam da comunidade `staff` (**pode estar enganado acho que é esse o nome** e não sei a hierarquia direito), mas, não sei também.

- Afinal na rede SE quem é que tem salário, alguém saberia dizer?
- Pode ser estranha a pergunta, mas, pelos desmandos, mudanças repentinas e as diversas ocasiões que desanimam moderadores e até nós que não temos essa função fico pensando vale a pena brigar para ser um moderador, staff ou algo assim?

Comment: Staff são os funcionários da SE, e essa informação fica disponível no perfil deles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/401803 - até onde sei, são os únicos que ganham $, embora eu ache que nem todos são "obrigados" a participar dos sites. Alguns membros do staff são [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/401803), que são os que atuam - [ou pelo menos deveriam atuar](/a/7985/112052) - mais próximos das comunidades. Sei que também tem devs e outros que às vezes postam no meta.SE, mas também não conheço toda a hierarquia.

Answer (score 9):

A resposta simples para isso é o que o hkotsubo já comentou. Falarei de outros pontos.

O que eu posso dizer é que se quer um salário bom vale a pena querer ser funcionário da SE. Eles pagam bem. Foram considerados uma empresa boa pra se trabalhar. Mas hoje tenho minhas dúvidas se isso ainda é verdade. A impressão que tenho que os funcionários nem gostam mais do que fazem, e não sei mais se é causa ou consequência do problema todo da rede.

Eu não vou colocar *links* aqui, mas no metão está cheio de informação como há descontentamento geral com a SE. No Tweeter também tem membros proeminentes da comunidade descascando a empresa.

Tem gente que por "questão ética" não fala mal depois de trabalhar lá, mas você sente como as coisas são. E pra falar a verdade parte do problema é o critério de seleção de funcionários. A SE ainda tem alguns dos melhores profissionais técnicos, mas pra lidar com a comunidade, é lamentável, eles não querem fazer isso, não querem assumir responsabilidade de nada, é tudo evasivo (não é minha constatação, pode pesquisar, estou dizendo o que as pessoas falam pela rede).

Há uma relação de inimizade da comunidade (especialmente moderadores) com a SE. E acontece dos dois lados, não é mais como no começo que não fazia diferença quem estava em que função dentro da comunidade. Só a SE pode reverter isso e voltar a tratar a comunidade como amigos e não como um número para captar recursos.

E a SE já prometeu que isso ia mudar algumas vezes, nunca muda. O site não é mais o que era no começo, havia um prazer em participar, havia uma cumplicidade da empresa e comunidade, hoje é tudo burocrático, distante e tensionado. Acho que começou pouco antes do lançamento do SOpt.

A gente não sabe toda pressão que eles sofrem também, não há transparência, não sabemos de tudo de errado que acontece dentro da empresa, só sabemos o que vemos. Sempre disseram que isso é especulação e não é real, mas o tempo vai sempre mostrando que a percepção da comunidade está certa.

Entenda que somos só marionetes no processo. A SE é uma *startup* como outra qualquer que captou muito dinheiro e terá que dar lucro para quem investiu, de um jeito ou de outro. A SE não estão aqui para fazer a internet um lugar melhor como diziam antes, e nem ousam continuar falando mais isso.

Quanto a ser moderador tem um outro problema. Não precisa de mais moderador, precisa de mais comunidade, eu já falei disso em [Como moderar o SOpt?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8349/101) e [Qual a postura da SE sobre a moderação comunitária?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8378/101). Eles ignoraram completamente. Eles agem como robôs. O site precisa de mais moderação comunitária e as pessoas não querem mais fazer isso.

Moderar com diamante é até fácil, tem bem menos coisas para fazer do que as pessoas pensam. Então essa eleição é um erro. Vai tirar uma pessoa da moderação comunitária para por diamante. Sim, quem passa ter o diamante tende a moderar comunitariamente menos, caso contrário complica muito a vida da pessoa.

Quando anunciaram a eleição conversei com duas pessoas para se candidatarem, uma delas deixou claro que o site já prejudica a vida dela só participando um pouco, com a moderação seria um fardo a mais e prejudicaria mais, não valeria a pena.

A moderação atual dá conta das tarefas que são exclusivas de quem foi eleito, e os moderadores atuais estavam preparados para continuar, mesmo com baixa participação, agora já não sei mais, tem gente que ficou muito desconfortável com a situação gerada pela SE e agora pode ser que nem queira mais continuar. A SE meteu os pés pelas mãos, mas não é nenhuma novidade, fazem isso o tempo, e nunca reconhecem que erraram. Pior, ignoram quando são questionados, é bem lamentável. Alias, eles instruem a moderação ignorar a comunidade também, eu prefiro sempre responder a tudo, então fico no meio do caminho, às vezes respondo, às vezes não.

Não vou repetir aqui que colocar mais ou novos moderadores não vai resolver problema algum. Pode causar novos. Ao contrário do que pensa algumas pessoas de acordo com as perguntas feitas em [Eleições para Moderador 2020 - Coleta de Perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8400/101) o moderador diamante não tem poder de fato, e não podem resolver problemas da comunidade não participativa, de qualidade das perguntas, de falta de votos, de interferência ou falta de atitude da SE em vários pontos, então todas candidaturas que falarem que farão algo ser melhor estarão agindo como políticos tradicionais, só falando o que as pessoas querem ouvir.

Moderadores só poderão fazer mais do que já está sendo feito, e fechar mais perguntas, punir mais os usuários fazendo coisas erradas. No máximo o que poderá ser diferente é um moderadores ter uma atitude de guerra com outros moderadores e subverter tudo o que está sendo feito, o que pode parecer bom por um lado, mas é só o único problema que faltava. Será muito ingrato para todos.

O fato é que quem quer que sejam os novos moderadores não vai ajudar nada em melhorias no site e corre-se o risco de entrar pessoas que só querem o bônus de ser moderador sem se importar com o ônus. Só tragédia.

Então a ação da SE é pura lambança, é uma atitude de robô que na melhor das hipóteses não trará benefícios, mas o mais provável é que traga problemas. Mas eles não se importam, quando der errado vão dizer que era só a comunidade agir certo. Eles ignoram que a comunidade é feita de pessoas, e pessoas diversas, parece que eles não entendem muito bem o que é diversidade, e não acontece de forma robótica o que eles esperam. Tem que analisar a situação concreta para tomar a melhor decisão. Que é o que eu vivo dizendo até sobre programação.

Sinceramente acho que tem poucos nomes que entendem o site, mostram disposição e podem contribuir positivamente na moderação diamante. Como alguns não vão se candidatar ou mesmo estão quase sem atividade, essa eleição não será boa para o site. Tomara estar errado e apareça alguém que faça ser diferente, mas acho que pelo menos uma pessoa vai ser mais problema que solução.

Particularmente não sei até quando serei moderador, hoje eu tenho uma vantagem por ser MVP, se não fosse, eu acho que já não seria. Deixarei de ser quando eu achar que está mais causando problema pra mim. Se você não tem vantagem alguma ser moderador, de verdade será só um fardo. Você vai se decepcionar. A não ser que a intenção da candidatura seja mal intencionada.

Aliás, ser MVP também é menos vantajoso do que as pessoas pensam, ajuda quem tem um viés mais marketeiro, sozinho o prêmio não serve para muita coisa.

Continuarei com toda vontade que sempre demonstrei, quando essa vontade acabar eu vou embora. Cada vez mais está valendo menos a pena.

Quem se importa com sua imagem, nem pense em se candidatar, você só se queima. Eu era mais feliz e mais bem avaliado pela comunidade quando não era moderador eleito. Novamente, a não ser que a candidatura seja mal intencionada.

Com sorte, nem sei se isso vale ainda, ganhará uma camisa, caneca, adesivos e uma doção em seu nome para alguma entidade, não vale o esforço, porque nem mesmo o reconhecimento real da SE você receberá. Discurso não é reconhecimento. Reconhecer é envolver no processo, é escutar de verdade, quando se faz coisas ignorando você, quando não se dá ao trabalho de explicar bem a situação, quando não se admite erro, não é reconhecimento.

Você ajuda mais a comunidade fazendo o trabalho comunitário. Espero que entre dois que não causem problema, é só isso que espero, mais nada. A única coisa que está faltando o que você já poderia estar fazendo.

Pra variar a SE deu um tiro no pé.

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e comçou a abranger outros pontos além da resposta, assim, foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113455/discussion-on-answer-by-maniero-quem-e-remunerado-na-rede), que é mais adequado para este tipo de interação. Para ler e/ou participar, basta clicar no link fornecido.